# Why SQL Server Ignores vaules in string concatenation when ORDER BY clause specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, concatenation

I have the following table

```
Created    Comment
2010/10/10 Text1 
2010/11/11 Text2
2010/12/12 Text3
```

I need gather all comments into the single string

```
SELECT  @Comment = COALESCE(@Comment, '')
   + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), [dbo].[Comment].[Created], 101) + ': ' + ISNULL([Comment].[Text], '')
    FROM Comment
```

Without ordering it works as expected end return all thee comments.
But after running following code where **ORDER BY** clause is added:

```
SELECT  @Comment = COALESCE(@Comment, '')
   + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), [Created], 101) + ': ' + ISNULL([Text], '')
    FROM Comment
  ORDER BY Created
```

Return only the last comment.
Does any body know why ORDER BY leads to the strange result in concatenation?

PS: It work fine if **FOR XML** clause used instead of concatenation [Is there a way to create a SQL Server function to “join” multiple rows from a subquery into a single delimited field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-sub).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are relying on undocumented behaviour.

Microsoft say "[The correct behavior for an aggregate concatenation query is undefined.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515/en-us)". If the compute scalar moves to the wrong place in the plan then it just stops working!