# Concatenating results of SELECT query only returns one value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using a select query together with a variable in order to concatenate some strings from a query, like so:

```
DECLARE @sConcat nvarchar(max)
SET @sConcat = ''
SELECT @sConcat = @sConcat + '[' + SomeColumn + ']'
 FROM SomeTable
 ORDER BY SomeColumn
```

In my particular case, I changed the `FROM` clause to a derived table, which just casts an integer column to nvarchar, so that I don't have to cast it every time it comes up in the concatenation.

After making this change, the result of the concatenation is **just one value out of those in the table**.  When moving the CAST to the outer query, or when removing the `ORDER BY` clause, the results are as expected.

This all can be reproduced with the following piece of t-sql.

```
BEGIN TRAN

-- Create a dummy table and populate it with some values
CREATE TABLE TTest (
    TTest_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    TTest_Text varchar(8) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT PK_TTest PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    TTest_Id ASC
 )
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO TTest (TTest_Text) VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO TTest (TTest_Text) VALUES ('B')
INSERT INTO TTest (TTest_Text) VALUES ('C')
INSERT INTO TTest (TTest_Text) VALUES ('D')
INSERT INTO TTest (TTest_Text) VALUES ('E')
INSERT INTO TTest (TTest_Text) VALUES ('F')
INSERT INTO TTest (TTest_Text) VALUES ('G')
INSERT INTO TTest (TTest_Text) VALUES ('H')

-- Create a string with the ID values of each row in brackets
DECLARE @sConcat nvarchar(max)

-- First attempt, produces the result '[8]' which is not what I expected
SET @sConcat = ''
SELECT @sConcat = @sConcat + '[' + TTest_ID + ']'
 FROM  (SELECT CAST(TTest_ID AS nvarchar(100)) AS TTest_ID, TTest_Text
         FROM TTest) TTestBis
 ORDER BY TTestBis.TTest_ID ASC

PRINT @sConcat

-- Second attempt, with cast in the outer query, 
-- produces the expected result '[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]'
SET @sConcat = ''
SELECT @sConcat = @sConcat + '[' + CAST(TTest_ID AS nvarchar(100)) + ']'
 FROM  (SELECT TTest_ID, TTest_Text
         FROM TTest) TTestBis
 ORDER BY TTestBis.TTest_ID ASC

PRINT @sConcat

-- Third attempt, same as first but without ORDER BY, 
-- also produces the expected result '[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]'
SET @sConcat = ''
SELECT @sConcat = @sConcat + '[' + TTest_ID + ']'
 FROM  (SELECT CAST(TTest_ID AS nvarchar(100)) AS TTest_ID, TTest_Text
         FROM TTest) TTestBis

PRINT @sConcat

ROLLBACK
```

Why does SQL Server behave this way?  To me it does not make sense.  I reproduced this on SQL Server 2005, 2008 and 2008R2.

**Edit**

This question is indeed a duplicate.  The best answer given so far seems to be the one by Martin Smith [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513%208593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior/15163136#15163136).  So you may vote to close.

Comment: Check this [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/214424/wrong-result-of-concatenation-when-order-by-used-in-the-query), this bug was reported to MS and not sure if they fixed that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why SQL Server Ignores vaules in string concatenation when ORDER BY clause specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538187/why-sql-server-ignores-vaules-in-string-concatenation-when-order-by-clause-speci)

Comment: @rs. They decided it was not a bug. [See Connect Item responses here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15163136/73226)

Comment: The article [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/214424/wrong-result-of-concatenation-when-order-by-used-in-the-query) has quite an exhaustive round up of the current methods. `XML PATH` being the most popular.

Comment: Indeed a duplicate (see my edit).  Best answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is indeed a duplicate.  A comprehensive answer can be found in the following stackoverflow question: [nvarchar concatenation / index / nvarchar(max) inexplicable behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior).

Several valid solutions to the problem of concatenating strings in a SELECT query are provided in this article: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score -1):

Wow!  At first look, you might think this is a bug.  My opinion is below after much analysis

I did all my testing in SQL Server 2012 developer version.  Let's go to query plan school.

-- Typical order by = sort operation
select * from TTest
order by TTest_Text desc;

[image]

-- Code 1
DECLARE @sConcat nvarchar(max) = '';
SELECT @sConcat = @sConcat + '[' + D1.TTest_ID2 + ']'
FROM  
  (SELECT CAST(TTest_ID AS nvarchar(100)) AS TTest_ID2, TTest_Text FROM TTest)  D1
ORDER BY D1.TTest_ID2;
PRINT @sConcat;

[image]

This produces the plan that looks correct but the wrong results.

-- Code 2
DECLARE @sConcat nvarchar(max) = '';
SELECT @sConcat = @sConcat + '[' + CAST(D2.TTest_ID AS nvarchar(100)) + ']'
FROM  (SELECT TTest_ID, TTest_Text FROM TTest) D2
ORDER BY D2.TTest_ID ASC;
PRINT @sConcat;

[image]

This produces a plan without a sort, wrong plan, but the right results.

I think you really need to think about the logical way SQL interprets the request.

1 - FROM
2 - WHERE
3 - GROUP BY
4 - HAVING
5 - SELECT
6 - ORDER BY

Thus, the derived query is calculated first.  We can not order the sub query because of the following restriction:

*The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, sub queries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.*

One would think that the (query optimizer / transaction manager) would calculate the string, then notice that it can not sort due to the fact you have N rows but 1 result.

In short, one would hope that both queries would either work correctly or fail.  Because they do not get the same plan, one query works and another does not.