# how to use sql for xml path('') but retain carriage returns

Tags: sql, xml

i have the following piece of code

```
select
    (
    select cast(Narrative as Varchar(max)) + char(13) 
    from officeclientledger 
    where ptmatter=$matter$ and ptTrans=4 
    for xml path (''), type
    )
```

which deliver results such as:

> Cwm Taff NHS Trust Medical Records
>    **;** Dr Purby Medical Records  **;**
>   *(excluding spaces, needed to insert for the purpose of asking the question)*

however, is there a way of delivering the results such as

> Cwm Taff NHS Trust Medical Records
>
> Dr Purby Medical Records

Comment: Do you want the carrige return to be rendered in the results grid, or when you copy and paste the text into [insert text editor here]?

Comment: i'm using this peice of code straighting into a word mail merge (a bit hacky i know), so there is no copy/pasting phase. but to be honest, i'm not too sure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can't be done using the results to grid functionality in SSMS. However, if you use the results to text option and replace your CHAR(13) with CHAR(10), you'll get the desired results.

Comment: cheers @Quickfire55 - cahing CHAR(13) with CHAR(10) worked :)

Comment: Also when you set it to Results to text, don't forget to extend the `Maximum number of characters displayed in each column`-configuration in Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Text. It's set to 256 by default in 2008R2 at least.

Answer (score 4):

I am hitting the same problem and i can't use Char(10) because the receiving system expect Char (13). So I used below query to replace the value in my result and it worked.

```
SELECT Coloumn = REPLACE(@v_Get_UPC_List, '&#x0D;', CHAR(13))
```

Answer (score 1):

When I have to use SSMS and want to see the values like requested, for testing, I use the print command.

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#doc') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #doc;
declare @doc varchar(max);

create table #doc (DOC varchar(max));
    insert into #doc EXECUTE db.[spDocumentJob] 1

SELECT @doc = STUFF(
    (SELECT  ' ' +  DOC + ' ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
        FROM #doc As T2
        ORDER BY DOC
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,'')
print @doc
```

[image]