# Problem in T-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called results and the data looks like:

```
Response_ID  order    [part label]             [Answer text]     [Answer label]
124587       6        It was not clear         NULL               Yes
124587       6        Did not Understand      Null                Yes
124589       6        Other (Please specify):  Not enough         Yes 
124563       1        NULL                     Satisfied?         Yes
124583       11       Not frequent             NULL               Yes  
125687       2        NULL                     Resolved?          NO
```

I want Output as:

```
Response_ID           [Part label]
124587                It was not clear,Did not Understand 
124589                Not enough         
124563                Yes
124583                Not frequent
125687                NO
```

The logic is whenever Order is 6 or 11 then I need to display the [Part Label] if the [Part Label] has multiple value for one Response_ID then I need to concatenate them but when the value of [Part Label] is Other (Please specify): then I need to use value from Answer Text column and if the order is not in 6,11 then I need to display the value from Answer label

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?  Are you looking to have us write your code for  you?  What have you tried?

Comment: @JNK I did refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614048/error-in-case-statement But the query I wrote is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had not seen the part about the order. I hope it works now.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Response_ID INT,[order] INT, [part label] VARCHAR(25), [Answer text] VARCHAR(15), [Answer label] VARCHAR(3))

INSERT @t VALUES (124587,6 , 'It was not clear'       , NULL        , 'Yes')
INSERT @t VALUES (124587,6 , 'Did not Understand'    , Null        , 'Yes' )
INSERT @t VALUES (124589,6 , 'Other (Please specify):','Not enough' , 'Yes')
INSERT @t VALUES (124563,1 , NULL                     ,'Satisfied?' , 'Yes')
INSERT @t VALUES (124583,11, 'Not frequent'           , NULL        , 'Yes') 
INSERT @t VALUES (125687,2 , NULL                     ,'Resolved?'  , 'NO' )

SET ARITHABORT ON

;WITH x AS   ( 
SELECT CASE WHEN [order] = 11 THEN 6 ELSE [order] END [order], response_id, COALESCE(CASE WHEN [part label] = 'Other (Please specify):' THEN [Answer text] ELSE [part label] end ,[Answer label]) [Part label] 
FROM @t
) 
SELECT response_id, STUFF(( 
        SELECT ',' + [Part label] 
        FROM x t1 
        WHERE t1.response_id = x.response_id and t1.[order] = x.[order]
        for xml path(''), type 
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') [Part label] FROM x
GROUP BY response_id, [order]
```

Result:

```
response_id Part label
----------- -------------------------------------
124563      Yes
124583      Not frequent
124587      It was not clear,Did not Undersstand
124589      Not enough
125687      NO
```

Comment: @ t-clause It works fine for the above sample data but it fails if one reponse_ID has different order values

Comment: I tried to adjust my script to work for different orders sets

Answer (score 1):

This used to be achieved through a little-known angle involving ISNULL(). These days, people do it with "FOR XML PATH". Note that this is not supported, but it will work for you right now.

[Concatenating Row Values in T-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

Too bad, there is no simple solution because Sql Server cannot concatenate result set rows. Look at these questions:

[Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

[How to create a SQL Server function to "join" multiple rows from a subquery into a single delimited field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-sub)

Comment: Although I did it in my script

Answer (score -1):

Check out the "The blackbox XML methods" section of the following article. I believe it will meet your needs.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/