# Create sql that will give me the product name separated by semicolon?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a product table like below. I would like to create a sql that will give me the product name separated by semicolon.

```
ProductName  AccountExpert
--------------------------
Tea          JohnSmith
Banana       GarySulvan
Water        JohnSmith
Candy        BobbySimmons
ConfecItem   BobbySimmons
Bread        JohnSmith
Soda         JohnSmith
```

Sql output should like this

```
AccountExpert  Products
-----------------------
JohnSmith      Tea; Water; Bread; Soda
GarySulvan     Banana
BobbySimmons   Candy; ConfecItem
```

Comment: What SQL engine are you using? (This is important because concatenation aggregation is actually pretty tricky and the answer may  depend on the engine and version you have.)

Comment: you should do a bit more research, and some effort before you post your question here. This is not a Q&A website, it's where people will help you if you've put some effort and are stuck somewhere !

Comment: @Tarun showing some effort is a nice gesture, sure, but...it's *not* a Q&A website?! Of course it is!

Comment: @Tarun: You are wrong; this is not a trivial question.  It's similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-sub).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

Comment: (So easy in SQLite... http://ideone.com/w7YpZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MS SQL you can use FOR XML, using the Stuff function to remove the excess delimiter. Unfortunately, there's no group concat function as with MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE #ProductExpert (ProductName nvarchar(20), AccountExpert nvarchar(20))

INSERT INTO #ProductExpert(ProductName, AccountExpert) SELECT
'Tea',          'JohnSmith'     UNION ALL SELECT
'Banana',       'GarySulvan'    UNION ALL SELECT
'Water',        'JohnSmith'     UNION ALL SELECT
'Candy',        'BobbySimmons'  UNION ALL SELECT
'ConfecItem',   'BobbySimmons'  UNION ALL SELECT
'Bread',        'JohnSmith'     UNION ALL SELECT
'Soda',         'JohnSmith'

SELECT DISTINCT
    ae.AccountExpert,
    Stuff((
        SELECT
             '; ' + p.ProductName
        FROM
            #ProductExpert AS p
        WHERE
            ae.AccountExpert = p.AccountExpert
        ORDER BY
            p.ProductName
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') AS Products
FROM
    #ProductExpert AS ae
ORDER BY
    ae.AccountExpert

DROP TABLE #ProductExpert
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using MySQL then use GROUPing and GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT AccountExpert, GROUP_CONCAT(ProductName SEPARATOR '; ')
FROM ProductExperts
GROUP BY AccountExpert
```

Comment: oh just noticed that you tagged question as sql-server-2008, quick googling returned this post: http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can try some of these ideas:

[Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

Bottom line is that there isn't a really elegant way to do this in SQL-Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://blog.namwarrizvi.com/?p=140

Its what you want to do, but with a `,` instead