# SQL query to concatenate one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

TABLE-A have the data as follows:

```
COLUMN1   COLUMN2
1         A
1         B
1         C
2         A
2         G
3         F
4         T
4         K
```

I want the RESULT as follows:

```
COLUMN1   COLUMN2
1         A,B,C
2         A,G
3         F
4         T,K
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to create a SQL Server function to "join" multiple rows from a subquery into a single delimited field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-su)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Description

You can use the `T-SQL` function `STUFF` for that.

#### Sample

```
SELECT COLUMN1, STUFF((
    select ','+ COLUMN2
    from YourTableName b
    WHERE a.COLUMN1 = b.COLUMN1
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
    ,1,1,'') AS COLUMN2
FROM YourTableName a
GROUP BY a.COLUMN1
```

#### More Information

[STUFF (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

Comment: @VenkateswarluAvula: please get in the habit of **accepting** the best answer provided, the one solving your problem. It's the right and polite thing to do on StackOverflow and serves as an incentive for others to continue to help those looking for answers. [See the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #con(
column1 int,
column2 varchar(10)
)
declare @column2 varchar(10), @col2 varchar(10)
declare @column1 int;
declare con_cursor cursor for
select column1, column2 from con
open con_cursor
fetch next from con_cursor into @column1, @column2
while(@@fetch_status=0)
begin
    if(@column1 not in (select column1 from #con))
    begin
        insert into #con values (@column1, @column2);       
    end
    else
    begin
        set @col2 = (select column2 from #con where column1=@column1);
        update #con set column2=(@col2+','+@column2) where column1=@column1;        
    end
    fetch next from con_cursor into @column1, @column2
end
select * from #con;
close con_cursor;
deallocate con_cursor;
truncate table #con;
```