# how to self join a table to get more info

Tags: sql-server, self-join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)
>   [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

I have a table customer (id, person_id, account number), id is primary key. For example

```
id   person_id    account number
1    0001         acc00011
2    0001         acc00012
3    0002         acc00021
```

Now I want to write a query to self join the table to get all the account numbers for each person. The result table should be

```
person_id    account
0001         acc00011, acc00012
0002         acc00021
```

How do I write the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that unless you want accounts concatenated in a single string by person_id.
See this questions:

- [How to create a SQL Server function to "join" multiple rows from a subquery into a single delimited field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-su)
- [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)
- [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: I tried the answer for the first link, it works. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [correlated subquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) with [FOR XML PATH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx) and [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) for the concatenation. Use [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) to remove preceding comma from results.

See example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5bd0/5