# Get Value separated by comma from the stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in sqlserver

```
UserID(PK)    Name    PhoneNumber
1             Test     123456
2             Test1    356456
```

And another table having FK of above table

```
 ID    RequestID   UserID(FK)
  1      20123        1
  2      20245        1
  3      21545        2
```

I need results as below

```
UserID    Name      phoneNumber  RequestID
 1        Test      123456       20123,20245
 2        Test1      356456       21545
```

I had used the join but that gives multiple records for each row but I need result as above.
Can anybody help how I should get this type of output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways that this could be done.

Using `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF`:

```
select u.userid,
  u.name,
  u.phonenumber,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + cast(r.requestid as varchar(10))
         from requests r
         where u.userid = r.userid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') requests
from users u;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/caf65/6)

Or you can use `CROSS APPLY` and `FOR XML PATH`:

```
select u.userid,
  u.name,
  u.phonenumber, 
  left(r.requests, len(r.requests)-1) requests
from users u
cross apply
(
  select cast(r.requestid as varchar(10)) + ', '
  from  requests r
  where u.userid = r.userid
  FOR XML PATH('')
) r (requests);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/caf65/7)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [UserID]
     , [Name]
     ,[PhoneNumber]
     , stuff((SELECT distinct ' ,'+ CAST(RequestID AS VARCHAR)
         FROM [Request] 
         WHERE (UserID = [PK].UserID) 
         FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,''
      ) AS Request1
FROM [PK]
```

**[I borrowed some concept from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-su)**

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9339/5)**