# Select field from table A where subselect from table B = table A field

Tags: sql-server

I need a little help getting the results I need. I have 2 tables with a common field of `id`. I want to combine the values from **table B** that have the same `id`

## Table A

```
id | name | somevalue1
1  | dud  | 12345
2  | duda | 8908
```

## Table B

```
id | somevalue2
1  | 56545
2  | 545665
1  | 89875
2  | 12524
```

## Desired Result

```
id | somevalue2 combined
1  | 56545, 89875
2  | 545665, 12524
```

I've tried using a `Join`, but I'm a bit lost. I have been attempting to do a subselect, but the only way I can think of to make it work is to reference the main query from within the subselect, but that aint gettin' it either.

This query I have been trying just hangs:

```
select distinct a.id,(
    select b.somevalue2 + ', ' as [text()] from tableB b 
    where b.id = a.id and b.somevalue2 is not null for xml path('')) 
    as [ColumnName]
from tableA a
order by a.id asc
```

## EDIT

I think I need to mention that **TableB** has over 400,000 rows. 
**TableA** has only about 1,500 rows.

Comment: Maybe you can find some help in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17591490/1385896)

Comment: I was just wondering if in the results under `Desired Results` is correct. The values in `somevalue2 combined` do not seem to have any values from `Table A`

Comment: @SecretSquirrel, that is intended

Comment: @SecretSquirrel - Yes that is correct. There are multiple values in tableB that I  need combined in one row per id number.

Comment: @OGHaza ah yes I misread the question. So `Table A` is really irrelevant in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT A.*,
       STUFF((
              SELECT ', ' + CAST([somevalue2] AS VARCHAR(20))
              FROM TableB B
              WHERE A.id = B.id
              FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM TableA A
```

[**Here is an sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ecfb0/2) for you to try.

Comment: Thank you! The query does take a long time to run however. TableB has over 400,000 rows. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @ckpepper02 Not many ways to do a fast group concatenation on SQL Server. Make sure that TableB has an index on `id` (even better if the index include columm `somevalue2`, something like `CREATE INDEX I_test ON TableB(id) INCLUDE(somevalue2);`)

Comment: Thanks again. The query took 14mins to run, but I got exactly what I was looking for so thank you!!