# SQL : Generate string of values in column

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a silly problem in sql
I had a column with some values in

```
  Column
    73
    74
    75
    76
    77
    78
    79
    80
    81
```

All i want to convert data in column into a string like

```
Declare Str as nvarchar(MAX)
Set Str = {Some Query};
```

**I HAD EDITED MY QUESTION**
Where **Str** is something like  **"[73],[74],[75],[76],[77],[78],[79],[80],[81]"**
What query should i made for doing this
Please suggest me.

Comment: You can do this with the FOR XML command
You can refer to this
[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It is not very clear. Also, the best thing would be to post what you have in the column and what is your desired output.

Comment: i want output string as i mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
DECLARE @Str AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Str = STUFF(
(
  SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([Column])
    FROM table1 
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
SELECT @Str list
```

Output:

```
|                                         LIST |
|----------------------------------------------|
| [73],[74],[75],[76],[77],[78],[79],[80],[81] |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e00a/7)** demo

Answer (score 1):

You will need to select the data into a cursor and then loop through each row at a time and build your string.  Probably best to write a stored procedure for this.

Something like

```
DECLARE #cTmp CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT myCol FROM myTable

OPEN #cTmp
FETCH NEXT FROM #cTmp INTO @MyVariableForTheColumn

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  --Build the string
  SET @String = @String + @MyVariableForTheColumn + ', '

 FETCH NEXT FROM #cTmp INTO @MyVariableForTheColumn
END
CLOSE #cTmp

DEALLOCATE #cTmp
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @s varchar(max) = ''

select @s += '[' + some_col + '],' from some_table

print @s
```

Comment: the query is correct, I just made a sqlfiddle to verify - what error are you getting? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c69d/1/0

Comment: @gordy do not forget to add @ to his name. otherwise will not know about your reply