# Pivoting row data into a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    testing VARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO #temp
  ( testing )
VALUES ('Boomerang')
INSERT INTO #temp
  ( testing )
VALUES ('Bowling')
INSERT INTO #temp
  ( testing )
VALUES ('Boxing')
INSERT INTO #temp
  ( testing )
VALUES ('Bull Fighting')


SELECT *
FROM #temp

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

And I'm trying to display it as a single column result like the following:

> Boomerang|Bowling|Boxing|Bull Fighting

However I've no idea how to do this. I've looked into Pivot but it doesn't seem to address my issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17591536/335858

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another way of doing it using `string concatenation` with `Isnull() [or coalesce()] function`.

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87071/1)**:

```
declare @str varchar(max)

Select @str = isnull(@str + '|', '') + testing
From temp
Order by testing

Select @str
--Results
Boomerang|Bowling|Boxing|Bull Fighting
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT STUFF(
        (
          SELECT '|' + testing
            FROM #temp
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') list
```

Output:

```
| LIST                                   |
|----------------------------------------|
| Boomerang|Bowling|Boxing|Bull Fighting |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed708/3)** demo

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?