# Return Comma separated values SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a field names DAILYREPORT.WEATHERCONDITION which can hold values as '1,2,3' or '1' or '2,4' based on what the user selects from the list of weather check boxes available to him. The weather table contains the list of weathers which he selects

```
Weather Table

ID  Condition
----------

1   Sunny    
2   Cloudy
3 Fine    
4 Windy
```

Now i need a query which returns the conditions as `'Sunny,Cloudy,Fine'` when `DAILYREPORT.WEATHERCONDION=1,2,3`

Comment: Sorry.. My bad.. I use sql-server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Comment: I am faster than my shadow

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
SELECT STUFF
(
     (select ',' + Condition
      from
      Weather
      where 
      ID in (1,2,3)
      FOR XML PATH('')
      ),1,1,''
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @list VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @list = COALESCE(@list+',' ,'') + Condition
FROM Weather
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)
SELECT @list
```

You declare a `@list` variable of `varchar` type. Then using the `COALESCE` expression (please look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx for further details on how it works) you get what you want.

That's a SQL fiddle that show that the above works as it is expected

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65df2/1

**Note** : In order to avoid any misconception, I don't say that the COALESCE solves the stated problem.

> It is is only there to deal with initializing the string and the issue
>   of a extra comma at the end.

as Mikael wrote below.

Comment: I don't think the downvote was because of the code. The code works. The description on how it works is however wrong. Coalesce has nothing to do with concatenating strings. Concatenating strings is done with `+` and this code uses an undocumented (as far as I know) feature that the variable is updated for each row in the select statement. `coalesce` is only there to deal with initializing the string and the issue of a extra comma at the end. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65df2/3

Answer (score 2):

mine is same as krishna,

```
Declare @Weather Table (ID int, Condition varchar(50))
insert into @Weather values(1,'Sunny'),(2,'Cloudy'),(3,'Fine'),(4,'Windy')

select top 1
stuff((select ','+Condition from @Weather b where id in(1,2,3) for xml path('')),1,1,'')Condition

 from @Weather
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope it is useful to Your

```
select SUBSTRING(
(select ','+  s.condition from DAILYREPORT s where id in (1,2,3) order by condition for xml path('')),2,200000) as CSV
```