# T-SQL GROUP BY - list instead of agregate function in the result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Is there any way to use GROUP BY in T-SQL but get "join-list" as a result instead of agregate function?
For example:

```
-- this table
CREATE TABLE tblDATA(
    Name int,
    GroupName nvarchar(50)
)

-- with this data
INSERT INTO tblDATA VALUES('Peter', 'A')
INSERT INTO tblDATA VALUES('Peter', 'B')
INSERT INTO tblDATA VALUES('Jane', 'A')
INSERT INTO tblDATA VALUES('Jane', 'C')
INSERT INTO tblDATA VALUES('Jane', 'D')
INSERT INTO tblDATA VALUES('Dave', 'B')
INSERT INTO tblDATA VALUES('Susan', 'E')
INSERT INTO tblDATA VALUES('Susan', 'F')


-- and get this query result in the two collumns (I don't care about delimiter) :
Peter       A, B
Jane        A, C, D
Dave        B
Susan       E, F
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Comment: Also read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691102/String-Aggregation-in-the-World-of-SQL-Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE #tblDATA(
    Name VARCHAR(20),     --<-- Your Name column is defined as INT Data Type 
    GroupName nvarchar(50)
)

-- with this data
INSERT INTO #tblDATA VALUES('Peter', 'A')
INSERT INTO #tblDATA VALUES('Peter', 'B')
INSERT INTO #tblDATA VALUES('Jane', 'A')
INSERT INTO #tblDATA VALUES('Jane', 'C')
INSERT INTO #tblDATA VALUES('Jane', 'D')
INSERT INTO #tblDATA VALUES('Dave', 'B')
INSERT INTO #tblDATA VALUES('Susan', 'E')
INSERT INTO #tblDATA VALUES('Susan', 'F')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, STUFF(List.Groups, 1 ,2 , '') AS Groups
FROM #tblDATA t  
            CROSS APPLY (
                        SELECT ', ' + GroupName [text()]
                        FROM #tblDATA
                        WHERE Name = t.Name
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        )List(Groups)
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════╦═════════╗
║ Name  ║ Groups  ║
╠═══════╬═════════╣
║ Dave  ║ B       ║
║ Jane  ║ A, C, D ║
║ Peter ║ A, B    ║
║ Susan ║ E, F    ║
╚═══════╩═════════╝
```