# Generate single row from multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I was working on stored procedure to return rows with columns from multiple table

First Table- `Product Variant`

```
Columns are - Sku, Name, Price, MRP, Cost
```

Second Table  - `Sku_Mrp_Mapping`

```
Columns are - Sku, MRP, Cost
```

Third Table- `Sku_Barcode_Mapping`

```
Columns are - Sku, Barcode
```

My query

```
SELECT     pv.Sku, pv.ProductCost, pv.Price, pv.Mrp,sb.Barcode,
           sm.MRP, sm.Cost
FROM         ProductVariant AS pv INNER JOIN
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Sku_MRP_Mapping AS sm ON sm.Sku = pv.Sku LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Sku_Barcode_Mapping AS sb ON sb.SKU = pv.Sku
WHERE     (p.Deleted = 0) AND (pv.Deleted = 0) and pv.Sku='100003'

ORDER BY pv.Sku
```

This result in 42 rows as for sku 100003 there are 7 barcodes and 6 different Mrp and cost.
My rows look like

For my Sku 100003 rows in Sku_Mrp_Mapping table are

```
Id    Sku    MRP     Cost
1   100003  65.00   58.19
2   100003  68.00   60.87
3   100003  72.00   64.45
4   100003  75.00   67.14
5   100003  78.00   69.83
6   100003  80.00   71.63
```

For my Sku 100003 rows in Sku_Barcode_Mapping table are

```
Id      SKU        Barcode
87942   100003  8901314009159
87943   100003  10000310
87944   100003  89013140090
87945   100003  8901314009081
87946   100003  8901314009111
87947   100003  8901314009159
87948   100003  10000320
```

Now I want to return single rows for sku 100003 with all barcodes in single column separated by comma and same for MRP and cost.

Note that I have taken 100003 sku as an example, there are many rows in productvariant which i want to return.

Comment: @marc_s couldnt get the expected answer from ur link, can u specify more precise solution?

Comment: Try [How to make a query with group_concat in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server) which has the usual for xml path solution. Or just search for sql server group_concat.