# Grouping pairs in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I ve following table:

```
id | group | decision | category
___ _______ _________
1  | 1111  | yes |  A
2  | 1111  | yes | B
3  | 2222  | no  | A
4  | 3333  | yes | A
5  | 3333  | yes | C
6  | 4444  | no  | A
7  | 4444  | no  | B
```

Now I'd like to count pairs and unique categories in the following way: (A,B) = 2, (A)=1, (A,C) = 1. Is it possible to write sql query which give such result?

Comment: do you have only `A`,`B` and `C`?

Comment: is it mysql or ms sql server?

Comment: a few more A,B,C,D and its multiplications (A,B)(A,C)(A,D)(B,C) and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can simply form all the groups using `GROUP_CONCAT` in a subquery, and count them in an outer query;

```
SELECT categories, COUNT(*) count
FROM (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(category ORDER BY category) categories
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY `group`
) z
GROUP BY categories;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc85a/1).

In TSQL, `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't exist, so you can use a trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

```
SELECT categories, COUNT(*) count
FROM (
  SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + mt.category
           FROM mytable mt
           WHERE m.[group] = mt.[group]
           ORDER BY mt.category
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).
                 value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') categories
  FROM mytable m
  GROUP BY [group]
) z
GROUP BY categories;
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cdae7/1).

Comment: Joachim, do you know any equivalent of GROUP_CONCAT in tsql? It seems that there is no any.

Comment: @arth81 Just added a TSQL version.

Comment: Joachim, I ve complicated situation a bit by adding another group : "decision". Now there should be two unique groups of (A,B): yes, no. I ve try to modify your code by adding: m.decision = mt.decision in where close and group but it seems that the core issue is depend on FOR XML PATH('') which I didn't catch fully. Could you explain me this? do you have any ideas how to modify this query?

Comment: @arth81 Are all decisions always the same within a group?