# Using Distinct and COALESCE Together using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I Have a table with below data

```
column1   column2

DIU02   3D ITEM MAINTENANCE
DIU02   DISTRIBUTION ITEM UPDATE APPLICATION
DIU02   DIU - Distribution Item Update
```

I want for unique DIU02 , all data come in single column using comma seperation.

Its for SQL Server Database

Below is the Query

DECLARE @Data VARCHAR(MAX)

```
SELECT @Data = COALESCE(@Data + ',', '') + column2
FROM Table
WHERE column1= 'DIU02'
```

I want to get only distinct data and I used distinct keyword but I am getting only one.

Please help !

Comment: You mean `T-SQL` with `SqlServer`, surely?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a query with group\_concat in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Comment: Yes StuartLC it is TSQL

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus But that particular syntax of `@var = @var + column` can in fact perform conacatenation

Comment: @Lamak Of course you're right, missed that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT @Data = COALESCE(@Data + ',', '') + column2
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT column2
  FROM Table
  WHERE column1= 'DIU02'
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're looking for that one (MS SQL):

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @List = COALESCE(@List + ',', '') + CAST(column2 AS VARCHAR)
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  column1 = 'DIU02'

SELECT @List
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40af5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this, if I understand you

```
select  col1,Stuff=Stuff((SELECT ',' + col2  FROM t t1 WHERE t1.col1=t.col1   

 FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '' )
from t
GROUP BY col1
```

[**Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0eeda/2)