# Merge data many rows of one column into a single row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like

```
create table temp_table (col1 int)
```

I have some data in this table like

```
insert into temp_table 
values(1), (2), (3), (4)
```

Now I want the data to be output as follows:

```
1,2,3,4
```

I have used the query:

```
select cast(col1 as nvarchar)+',' 
from temp_table 
for xml path('')
```

The problem is that the output comes in XML format and i need it in simple text/string format. I tried searching for transpose but `FOR XML()` was mentioned everywhere and it didn't helped me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: You need STUFF and XML_PATH, like there : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17591536/961526

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @temp nvarchar(max)
select @temp = COALESCE(@temp + ', ', '') + CAST(col1 as nvarchar) from temp_table
select @temp
```

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus yups !!, see updated...

Answer (score 3):

And if you really don't get it with the given link :

```
select STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + cast(col1 as nvarchar)
          FROM temp_table
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Query

```
Select STUFF((SELECT ',' + Cast(col1 As nvarchar) FROM temp_table 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') As MyColumn
```