# Select a list of comma-separated postcodes to an ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a record set:

```
ID  Postcode

1   S43 4AX
1   S43 4PE
1   S43 4XE
1   S43 4XN
10  S43 4AB
10  S43 4AD
10  S43 4AG
10  S43 4AH
10  S43 4AJ
10  S43 4AL
```

From which I want to select out:

```
ID    PostcodeList

1     S43 4AX, S43 4PE, S43 4XE, S43 4XN
10     S43 4AB,S43 4AD,S43 4AG,S43 4AH,S43 4AJ,S43 4AL
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL? Access? Teradata? Sql Server?

Comment: Why don't you do a `SELECT ID,PostCode FROM TableName WHERE id=1 OR id=10` and then stitch them together in the server code using implode/String.Join etc (php/java/c#) or even front-end like javascript if it is not that many rows ?

Comment: If you're using MySQL, see `GROUP_CONCAT()`. There are similar mechanisms for other databases.

Comment: Check this for MS SQL SERVER http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Comment: This is a presentation issue. This is not a job for SQL to handle - leave it to your front-end report/webpage/form/etc.

Comment: in Postgresql you can use: `string_agg(field, delimiter)`

Comment: P.S. because people love points, they're going to tell you various methods to solve your problem. However they are almost exclusively bodges/workarounds to a problem that should simply be solved in another language/technology. Just because it can be done, doesn't mean it should.

Comment: @gvee we'll probably disagree at this point, but every major RDBMS has the ability to concatenate results in a field level group by. I would rely on the RDBMS and its often very well refined execution path to perform this rather than writing code on the front end to iterate through a recordset clumsily stitching together records. One pass at the data versus two means better consolidated resources, less confusion for the next person maintaining your app, and less chance for error.

Comment: Appologies should have said Its MS SQL 2008 R2

Comment: This is required in Tsql as the next step is to mail out the list of postcodes, using the sql server

Comment: Read [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/), it goes over all the available options and discusses pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code sugested by Michail Michailidis to write this

```
Select Distinct a.id, CAST((
          SELECT  T.postcode+','
          FROM mtable T
          WHERE A.id = T.id
          FOR XML PATH(''))as varchar(max)) as pclist
FROM mtable a
```