# SQL Server: Select multiple records in one select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

In a query like this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Order`
WHERE `CustID` = '1'
```

My results are displayed like so:

```
| CustID| Order |
-----------------
| 1     | Order1|
| 1     | Order2|
| 1     | Order3|
-----------------
```

How do I write SQL statement, to get a result like this one?:

```
| CustID| Order                 |
---------------------------------
| 1     | Order1, Order2, Order3|
---------------------------------
```

In mySQL it's possible with `Group_Concat`, but in SQL Server it gives error like syntax error or some.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a query with group\_concat in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Comment: Try googling "SQL Server group_concat`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27341271/1080354

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use xml path ([see fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4274/6/0))

```
SELECT distinct custid, STUFF((SELECT ',' +[order]
FROM table1 where custid = t.custid
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM table1 t
where t.custid = 1
```

STUFF replaces the first `,` with an empty string, i.e. removes it. You need a distinct otherwise it'll have a match for all orders since the where is on custid.

[FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)
[PATH Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms189885.aspx)
[STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

Comment: I see we thought about the same thing... :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled 1 minute too late :) Great minds think alike so have a 1+ :)

Comment: Just edit your links to make it more readable and you'll have a great answer. still got my upvote :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled How? Put a newline between them but yeah doesn't look right. Can you edit?

Comment: click on the edited link and see... Note that for a line break you need 2 spaces before the actual line break

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Stuff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function and [`For xml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) clause like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT CustId, STUFF((
   SELECT ','+ [Order]
   FROM [Order] T2
   WHERE T2.CustId = T1.CustId
   FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, '')
 FROM  [Order] T1
```

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0dbc1/1)

**Note:** Using `order` as a table name or a column name is a very, very bad idea. There is a reason why they called reserved words *reserved*.
See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30132058/3094533) for my favorite way to avoid such things.

Answer (score -1):

try this. 
Change table name and column names for what you need;

```
SELECT custID, 
       LISTAGG(Order, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Order) text
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY custID
```

edit for MSSQL . You should use group_concat function.

```
SELECT custID, GROUP_CONCAT(Order)
  FROM table_name
 WHERE CustID = 1
 GROUP BY custID;
```

Comment: It is about `SQL Server`, there is no such function as `LISTAGG` there.

Comment: Again, there is no ` group_concat` function in `Microsoft SQL Server` :-)

Comment: sql server does not have group_concat either.