# SQL Server array_agg (master - detail)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I convert this PostgreSQL code to SQL Server ?

```
select 
    countries.title, 
    (select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t))) 
     from postcodes t 
     where t.country_id = countries.id) as codes 
from countries
```

My initial problem is that I need to select complete master table and with each row all details.

**Countries**:

```
id    title
1     SLO
2     AUT
```

**PostCodes**:

```
id  country_id  code    title
1   1           1000    Lj
2   1           2000    Mb
3   2           22180   Vi
4   2           22484   De
```

Desired result:

```
1  SLO  1000;Lj|2000;MB
2  AUT  22180;Vi|22484;De
```

Not:

```
1  SLO  1000  Lj
1  SLO  2000  Mb
2  AUT  22180 Vi
2  AUT  22484 De
```

The best solution would be using [FOR JSON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921882.aspx), but unfortunately I need support for 2008 or at least 2012.

With left join all master data are duplicated for detail count, but I do not want to do this. Even worse it would be to select all countries and then call select on `post_codes` for every country in for loop.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 is no longer supported. 2012 is the earliest supported version, although 2016 is the obvious choice since you get Columnstore indexes, compression, in-memory tables, partitioning even in SQL Server Express and LocalDB (with SP1). It may be cheaper to upgrade than code JSON generation in T-SQL

Comment: I know but convincing 500 clients that they should bought newer SQL is mission impossible. They want that our product would work with 2005. Insane if you ask me. :)

Comment: Even though their data could fit in the free SQL Server Express version? Anyway, such conversions are far easier and safer on the *client*. String manipulation in the database is expensive. Besides, what are you going to do if some data requires escaping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select countries.title, 
       STUFF((select '|' + t.code + ';' + t.title
                from postcodes t 
                where t.country_id = countries.id
                FOR XML PATH('')
              ),1,1,'') as codes 
     from countries
```

-- CAST t.code to VARCHAR if it's Number

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select Main.COUNTRY_ID,c.title,Left(Main.POSTCODES,Len(Main.POSTCODES)-1) As "POSTCODES"
From
    (
        Select distinct ST2.COUNTRY_ID, 
            (
                Select ST1.CODE+';'+ST1.TITLE + '|' AS [text()]
                From dbo.POSTCODES ST1
                Where ST1.COUNTRY_ID = ST2.COUNTRY_ID
                ORDER BY ST1.COUNTRY_ID
                For XML PATH ('')
            ) [POSTCODES]
        From dbo.POSTCODES ST2
    ) [Main]

    inner join countries c on c.id=main.country_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `XML PATH` for concatenation can increase the complexity of your code. It's better to implement a [CLR aggregation function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27341271/1080354). Then, you can do the following:

```
SELECT C.[id]
      ,C.[title]
      ,REPLACE([dbo].[Concatenate] (P.[code] + ';' + P.[title]), ',', '|')
FROM @Countries C
INNER JOIN @PostCodes P
    ON C.[id] = p.[country_id]
GROUP BY C.[id]
        ,C.[title];
```

You can create your own version of the concatenate aggregate - you can specify the delimiter, the order, etc. I can show you examples if you want.

```
DECLARE @Countries TABLE
(
    [id] TINYINT
   ,[title] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @Countries ([id], [title])
VALUES (1, 'SLO')
      ,(2, 'AUT');

DECLARE @PostCodes TABLE
(
    [id] TINYINT
   ,[country_id] TINYINT
   ,[code] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[title] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @PostCodes ([id], [country_id], [code], [title])
VALUES (1, 1, 1000, 'Lj')
      ,(2, 1, 2000, 'Mb')
      ,(3, 2, 22180, 'Vi')
      ,(4, 2, 22484, 'De');

SELECT C.[id]
      ,C.[title]
      ,REPLACE([dbo].[Concatenate] (P.[code] + ';' + P.[title]), ',', '|')
FROM @Countries C
INNER JOIN @PostCodes P
    ON C.[id] = p.[country_id]
GROUP BY C.[id]
        ,C.[title];
```

[image]