# Add some specific value in each digit of number in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need the formula for calculating some number

(1) Add 3 in each digit of the particular number

(2) If we get the result after addition in two digits like 10,11,12 etc then consider only last digit

For example if number would be 564843530 then `enter code here`
New number would be 897176023.

Comment: Did you try anything? if yes show us please

Comment: Shouldn't `564843530` become `897176863`? How is `5 + 3 = (1)0`? and `3 + 3 = 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ty this:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT RIGHT(SUBSTRING(DS.[number], v.[number] + 1, 1) + 3, 1)
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT '564843530' 
    ) DS ([number])
    INNER JOIN [master]..spt_values v on v.[number] < LEN(DS.[number])
    WHERE V.[type] = 'P'
    ORDER BY v.[number] 
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)');
```

The algorithm is simple:

1. split the string to chars (in your case numbers)
2. add 3 to each number
3. using RIGHT get the first right char only
4. concatenate the numbers

This should work on older editions. If you are using `SQL Server 2016` you can use functions like `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG` in `SQL Server 2017`.

For older version you can look for SQL CLR function in order to write your own functions for splitting and concatenating. For example, in my system I can do:

[image]

Check the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27341271/1080354) if interested in SQL CLR.

Comment: @Rob The solution is there as T-SQL code and can be copied. The other statement is applicable for my environment only - the screenshot display proof of concept and work. Please, read the answers first and flag them only if you understand them.

Comment: @gotqn Simple answer for expected result and i am impressed with this answer bro i was writing script for this question with some additional steps,but is topped myself not to post by seeing your answer .

Comment: @Sreenu131 Thanks. Don't worry, there is nothing wrong to provide another solution (if it is not yet posted).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

```
DECLARE @number int
SET @number = 564843530;

WITH DigitsTable AS 
(
    SELECT 0 AS Power10, ABS(@Number) AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Power10 + 1, Number / 10
    FROM DigitsTable
    WHERE Number > 10
)
SELECT SUM((((Number % 10) + 3) % 10) * POWER(10, Power10)) AS NewNumber
FROM DigitsTable
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Output:

```
897176863
```

**Explanation:**

This answer is based on one recursive CTE which returns each current digit, new digit and multiplier for calculation:

```
DECLARE @number int
SET @number = 564843530;

WITH DigitsTable AS 
(
    SELECT 0 AS Power10, ABS(@Number) AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Power10 + 1, Number / 10
    FROM DigitsTable
    WHERE Number > 10
)
SELECT 
    Power10,
    Number % 10 AS Digit,
    ((Number % 10) + 3) % 10 AS NewDigit,
    POWER(10, Power10) AS Multiplier
FROM DigitsTable
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Output from recursive CTE:

```
Power10 Digit   NewDigit    Multiplier
0       0       3           1
1       3       6           10
2       5       8           100
3       3       6           1000
4       4       7           10000
5       8       1           100000
6       4       7           1000000
7       6       9           10000000
8       5       8           100000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the example value supplied by the OP is wrong (as, per my comment *"Shouldn't `564843530` become `897176863`? How is `5 + 3 = (1)0`? and `3 + 3 = 2`?"*), then this is my method, which makes use of [NGrams8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/):

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT 564843530 AS SomeNumber),
Split AS(
    SELECT V.SomeNumber,
           NG.token,
           NG.position
    FROM VTE V
         CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k(V.SomeNumber,1) NG)
SELECT SomeNumber AS OldNumber,,
       CONVERT(bigint,(SELECT token + 3
                       FROM Split x
                       WHERE S.SomeNumber = x.SomeNumber
                       ORDER BY x.position
                       FOR XML PATH(''))) AS NewNumber
FROM Split S
GROUP BY S.SomeNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @n int, @inc int;
SELECT @n = 564843530, @inc = 3;
WITH t1(n, m, k, p)
AS (
   SELECT @n AS n, CAST(0 AS int) AS m, CAST(0 AS int) AS k, CAST(0 AS bigint) AS p
   UNION ALL
   SELECT n / 10 AS n, n - round(n, -1, 1) AS m,  k + 1 AS k, CAST(power(10, k) AS bigint) AS p
   FROM t1 WHERE n > 0
)
SELECT SUM((CASE WHEN m > 10 - @inc THEN m - 10 + @inc ELSE m + @inc END) * p)
FROM t1
```

Result

```
897176863
```