# Replace the last item's comma separator with "and" in Sql STUFF Command

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

If the output of my query is England, America, India.

Is it possible to display the query result like England, America **and** India

Here is my query:

```
Select stuff( ( Select Distinct ',' + Country as[text()] 
from tbl_Country 
where OrderNo in (Select Max(OrderNo) from Tbl_Literature where ID='AB123' 
                  Group By OrderNo) for XML path('') ),1,1,'')as Result 
from dbo.Tbl_Master as TP 
where 
  TP.OrderNo IN (select MAX(order No) from dbo.Tbl_Master where TP.ID = 'AB123')
```

Comment: Will your query return "England, America, India" in one column?

Comment: Yes it returns, I want to append "and" string before the last item "India".

Comment: How are you getting the concatenated string?

Comment: Here is my query: Select 
stuff(
(
 Select Distinct ','  +  Country as[text()] from tbl_Country
 where OrderNo in (Select Max(OrderNo) from Tbl_Literature where ID='AB123' Group By OrderNo) for XML path('')
),1,1,'')as Result 
from dbo.Tbl_Master as TP
where TP.OrderNo IN (select MAX(order No) from dbo.Tbl_Master where TP.ID = 'AB123')

Comment: My query is can I append "and" before the India

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the string aggregation hack done to compensate for SqlServer's lack of  [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591536/314291), you can use this [ingenious hack](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/446034/Replace-last-occurrence-of-comma-with-and) here:

```
WITH myStuffedCte AS
(SELECT 
    STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + Name
          FROM Country
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS SomeCol
)
SELECT ISNULL(reverse(replace(STUFF(reverse(SomeCol),
                      charindex(',',reverse(SomeCol)),0,'#'),'#,',' dna ')),
              SomeCol)
FROM myStuffedCte;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7e0fc/1)

**Updated example of Stuff with a `GROUPING` criteria**

In order to use `STUFF` in a `GROUP BY` fashion, you can manually filter the inner STUFF subquery based on an outer query's rows with a `WHERE` clause.

```
WITH myStuffedCte AS
(
    SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName,
        STUFF((
              SELECT ',' + c.Name
              FROM Country c
              INNER JOIN PersonCountryVisits pcv
              ON pcv.CountryId = c.CountryId
              WHERE pcv.PersonId = p.PersonID -- Manual Filter step
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS SomeCol
    FROM Person p
)
SELECT FirstName, LastName,
   ISNULL(reverse(replace(STUFF(reverse(SomeCol),
          charindex(',',reverse(SomeCol)),0,'#'),'#,',' dna ')), 
          SomeCol) AS CountriesVisited
FROM myStuffedCte;
```

[Updated Sql Fiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/08db9/2)

**SqlClr Alternative to `Stuff`, IFF you can use SqlClr on your SqlServer:**
If you have access to a Sql-Clr enabled SqlServer, you can ditch both of these hacks and instead, replace `STUFF / FOR XML` with a `GROUP_CONCAT simulation of SqlUserDefinedAggregate` [like this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056.aspx), and at the same time do the last comma replacement with a `SqlFunction` UDF, like this:

```
[SqlFunction]
public static SqlString ReplaceLast(SqlString source, SqlString find, SqlString replace, 
                                    int countFromRight)
{
    var splits = source.Value
        .Split(new[] {find.Value}, StringSplitOptions.None);

    var replacePoint = splits.Length - countFromRight;

    return (replacePoint > 0)
        ? new SqlString(
            string.Join(replace.Value,
                new[] { string.Join(find.Value, splits.Take(replacePoint)) }
                .Union(splits.Skip(replacePoint))))
        : source;
}
```

In which case the sample query becomes the entirely more palatable:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, 
    dbo.ReplaceLast(dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(c.Name, ','), ',', ' and ', 1)
FROM  Person p 
    INNER JOIN PersonCountryVisits pcv
    ON pcv.PersonId = p.PersonID
    INNER JOIN Country c
    ON pcv.CountryId = c.CountryId
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName;
```

I've put up a [Gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/nonnb/465a355fda05707c82cc) which provides all the salient bits to create the `GROUP_CONCAT` and `ReplaceLast` SqlClr functions. (SqlFiddle not available - No SQLClr ...)

Comment: StaurtLC: I am able to get the output as expected but the query eliminates other columns. With the country column I have other Columns like FirstName, LastName and other user details to be displayed. In this only country column need to be concatenated with respect to id, rest are singular

Comment: So the trick here is then to return all the necessary columns from the CTE, and in addition, to manually filter each inner loop of the `STUFF` hack back to the group table. I've taken a stab at guessing your data model - [Updated Sql Fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d1a40/1).

Comment: Many thanks StaurtLC.. I am able to get the output as expected :)

Comment: @StaurtLC  i need your help for the above query. If the query result has only country like "New Zealand" then the result is displayed as null.. I tried using Case statement, but its in vain

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned the stuff command, I assume you are using `FOR XML PATH('')` to concatenate your items, and `STUFF` to remove the first delimiter, e.g.

```
SELECT  STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + Country
                FROM    InnerTable AS i
                WHERE   i.ID = o.ID
                ORDER BY Country
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM    OuterTable AS o;
```

If this is the case then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the last row (by using the inverse ordering to the subquery), and put `AND` in there:

```
SELECT  STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Country DESC) = 1 
                                    THEN 'and ' 
                                    ELSE '' 
                                END + Country
                FROM    InnerTable AS i
                WHERE   i.ID = o.ID
                ORDER BY Country ASC
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM    OuterTable AS o;
```

*n.b. The above will result in a string [serial comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) (e.g. "England, America, and India"), but it won't require much manipulation to change this.*

**SIMPLE EXAMPLE**

```
SELECT  STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Country DESC) = 1 
                                    THEN 'and ' 
                                    ELSE '' 
                                END + Country
                FROM    (VALUES ('America'), ('England'), ('India')) AS i (Country)
                ORDER BY Country ASC
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '');
```

Comment: GarethD: I tried with the above query. It is appending the "and" string @first. i.e. ,andEngland, America, India.

Comment: Then you are using the same order by criteria in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function as you are in the subquery, the must be the opposite, note in the answer I have `ORDER BY Country DESC` inside the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, but `ORDER BY Country` in the subquery. (Although I did have the `ORDER BY` in the wrong place, I have corrected this and also added `ASC` to make it clear that the ordering is inverted)

Comment: when it results in a single County it still puts "and " at the beginning. How do we avoid this? i.e. "and America"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Declare @String varchar(100)

    set @String = 'England, America, India'

    SELECT reverse(replace(STUFF(reverse(@String),
           charindex(',',reverse(@String)),0,'#'),'#,',' dna '))
```

Comment: When writing code like this any assumptions/conditions should be explicitly stated.  For example, this ***requires*** each item in the list to ***not*** end with `#`.  Also, as it is post-processing the aggregation, the last item in the list should not contain a `,`.

Comment: Also, what is its behaviour with a list of 1 item?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTRING()`. Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181984.aspx) for more `String` functions

```
 DECLARE @s AS VARCHAR(100)

 SET @s = 'England, America, India'

 SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, 0, LEN(@s) -  CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@s)) + 1 ) 
        + ' and' 
        + SUBSTRING(@s, LEN(@s) -  CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@s)) + 2, len(@s))
```