# How to dynamically calculate sum of multiple unknown columns in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple columns with some amount in a table and I want to show the total of all those amounts in the last Total column. I have a table in sql which looks somewhat like this,

```
A_Amt  B_Amt  C_Amt  D_Amt  E_Amt  F_Amt ... Total
------------------------------------------------
 15     20     25     30     35    40
```

I do not want to do `sum(col1 + col2 + ..)` like this because there are many columns. Is there another way to get the sum using a where clause like `**where columnname.name like '%Amt%'**`?

I am trying to use `UNPIVOT` and I came up with the following code but it is not working,

```
select Product_ID, Amount
FROM Products
unpivot
(Amount for Product_ID in 
(select c.name + '' from syscolumns c(nolock) where (id = 
(select id from dbo.sysobjects where name = 'Products'))
and (c.name like '%Amt%')))
```

Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: Can you change your schema?

Comment: You could look into using UNPIVOT.   But personally, I'd go with the (Col1 + Col2 +...) solution, which will probably perform the best, and I'm not lazy.

Comment: Your table has repeating groups and therefore is de-normalized.  Sorry, querying it is often going to suck, and there's no way around it.  It's the fault of your schema.

Comment: Okay...how many columns do you have ? Would it be okay if the sum(.....) query was automatically generated for you ?

Comment: I have 54 columns and yes it would be okay if the sum query was automatically generated.

Comment: simply do `SELECT A_Amt + B_Amt + C_Amt + D_Amt + E_Amt + F_Amt`

Comment: @Arpita - Good. Now, would you be willing to get the answer yourself if I gave you the main steps to get what you need ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [dyanamic UNPIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985796/pivot-dynamic-columns-no-aggregation/11985946#11985946) solution would need to use one of the [GROUP_CONCAT hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27378284/314291) to scrape the column names you've obtained via `sys.syscolumns` into a comma delimited string before entering into the UNPIVOT.

But if blinding performance isn't a requirement, how about invoking xquery to do this in Xml? It's much simpler:

```
declare @xmlResult xml=
(   
    select  * 
    from    Foo 
    for xml PATH
);

SELECT Nodes.node.value('sum(*[contains(local-name(.), "_Amt")])', 'decimal(15,2)') AS Total
  FROM
  @xmlResult.nodes('//row') as Nodes(node);
```

[With a SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/97f5d/3)

Basically, after rolling up the whole table into Xml, it then iterates the rows (`//row`), evaluating the sum of all the elements with a `name` which contains `_Amt`.

The real benefit is that you don't need to bother figuring out the actual column names at all - that'll be deferred into the `xpath`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unusual table layout, and I don't think there's a perfect shortcut for what you want to do. One option is to push the addition to the table level with a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD Total AS A_Amt + B_Amt + ... + zz_Amt;
```

After the initial trouble of setting up the computed column, your future queries get a lot easier:

```
SELECT Total FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll be using Dynamic SQL. Google a simple example for this.

1 - Generate a string with all column names - c1+c2+c3...

2 - Create a string with full sql query, using 1 also.

3 - Execute string in 2 as dynamic sql.

I'll combine 1 and 2 though.

```
declare @sql  varchar(max)
set @sql = 'SELECT ' 

declare @tbl varchar(100)
set @tbl = 'temp' -- put your table name here

SELECT @sql = @sql + COLUMN_NAME + '+'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tbl 
-- AND TABLE_SCHEMA='junk'

set @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1)
set @sql = @sql + ' FROM ' + @tbl

select @sql

-- dynamic sql

exec(@sql)
```