# using TYPE (via sqlserver 2008) command limits buffer size to 255

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, cmd

I am using  master.dbo.xp_cmdshell to load txt/csv file to SQL server, in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempoutput
(
    result_id [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    result  VARCHAR(MAX)
)


INSERT INTO #tempoutput(result)
EXEC @rcode = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell TYPE c:\test.csv
```

the thing is that although result column is defined as VARCHAR(MAX), when I try to take header with:

```
SELECT  top 1 @result=result
FROM    #Tempoutput
```

I can only fetch 255 characters, any reason why? and how to be able to fetch all row till CRLF

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The result does contain all the data, its just broken into multiple rows of 255 chars in your `#tempoutput` table. (Remove the TOP 1 to see all the rows)

```
INSERT INTO #tempoutput(result)
  EXEC @rcode = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell "TYPE c:\ReallyBig.csv"
SELECT * FROM #tempoutput; -- You'll see the extra rows
```

If you need to reassemble all lines back into a single VARCHAR(MAX), you'll need to use your favourite [GROUP_CONCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17591490/314291) hack. Since you're already using `xp_cmdshell`, you probably have unlimited access to your server, so why not install a [CLR aggregate function like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056.aspx) with [example usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27378284/314291) to do just this - IMO this is much more readable than the `FOR XML ... STUFF` hacks.

Comment: Thanks. I just need the header (or a complete record to end of line) so I was able to reassemble it using a simple loop that fetches rows until len <> 255. not optimal but do the work. just thought there is a more elegant way to fetch a complete row, not reassembling it.

Comment: Again, SqlServer's string manipulation functions are lousy here. You can use a [PARSENAME or PATINDEX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco) hack to get the first string before the CRLF, or use a UDF, or again, install a CLR function for string splitting?