# Incorrect XML parsing in SQL Text

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I have a piece of sql text which uses:

```
Cast ('< M>' + Replace(JobNote, ',', '< /M>< M>') + '< /M>' AS XML)
```

and when i execute it the error generated is:

> XML parsing: line 1, character 23, illegal name character  can someone
>   tell me what should I do??

(please ignore the blankspace before `M>` in `< M>`)

Comment: What does JobNote contain?

Comment: Varchar ....JobNote contains string
i am actually trying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543755/appending-data-in-t-sql/27551232#27551232 
so i have another part in the first select which fetches:
Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') JobNote

Comment: Alex K mean what is the content of JobNote.   Some character in there is illegal

Comment: oh. such as &, <,>, etc..you mean?? what if I do need to keep those characters.....is there some way around this?

Comment: Don't cast as XML? You can't use that output externally, so...

Comment: Use one of the `FOR XML ...` forms to apply escaping

Comment: i am new to this sql and xml casting...can someone give an example of how to go around it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space in `< M>` is what not allowing to cast the string as `XML` remove the space like

```
select Cast ('<M>' + Replace(JobNote, ',', '</M>') + '</M>' AS XML)
```

then it will work fine.

And There are few special characters are invalid in `XML` so it has to be replaced in `JobNote` with the following.

```
& - &amp;
< - &lt;
> - &gt;
" - &quot;
' - &#39;

select Cast ('<M>' + Replace(JobNote, ',', '</M>< M>') + '</M>' AS XML)
```