# SUM string with comma (SQL Server Reporting Services)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services

I would like to get string sum check "column 1".

Do you have idea how to do it?

```
jack, john, bill, joe, sindy
```

[image]

Something similar to

```
=JOIN(Fields!Column1.Value, ",")
```

Comment: To do this in tsql, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server . I don't think it's possible to do it in SSRS alone.

Comment: I have to do it this in SSRS :(

Comment: What SSRS version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Version MSSQL 2008

Comment: What is the source for the data your are reporting - is it a relational database (such as SQLServer), a text file or something else? (If it's SQLServer, you can do this in tsql.)

Comment: I can`t because I use stored procedure which is created by another person.

Comment: You say that is MSSQL 2008 not MSSQL 2008 R2? For R2 version you could use the LookupSet function for getting all values from a clumn in a dataset.

Comment: My MSSQL version is 2008 R2

Comment: what about adding a custom aggregation? i think this should work http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/07/20/using-group-variables-in-reporting-services-2008-for-custom-aggregation.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(COLUMN1 VARCHAR(100),COLUMN2 VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 'jack',1  
UNION ALL
SELECT 'john',1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bill',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'joe',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sindy',1
```

**QUERY**

If you need the value with `comma separate values` and `count`, you can avoid query before `UNION ALL` and execute the query only after `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT NULL,COLUMN1,COLUMN2
FROM #TEMP

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT 'TOTAL',
-- Here we convert to comma separated values
SUBSTRING(
            (SELECT  ', ' + COLUMN1
            FROM #TEMP T2 
            --WHERE C2.Id=Id AND C2.COLUM=COLUM            
            FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) COLUMN1,
COUNT(COLUMN1) COLUMN2
FROM #TEMP T1
```

Comment: I can`t do it this in sql :( but i will accept your answer.

Comment: Which version of Sql are u using? @Rafael - Junior MVC Developer

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 but  I use stored procedure which is created by another person and I can`t edit.