# SQL Database Query selecting different corresponding values for one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the output like this from the table?
If I have a table for example shown below

```
First Name         Last Name
----------    

 1. John            Doe
 2. John           Ruggles
 3. Ricky          Rog
 4. kelly          Ali
 5. Ricky           Gyri
```

I want to show this as below

```
First Name       Last Name

 1.John           Doe
                  Ruggles

 2. Kelly         Ali

 3. Ricky         Rog
                  Gyri
```

Like for each name I want to display last name. I want First Name will appear only one time. Please help me. Its a tabular data, first name and last name are different columns

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft MS SQL

Comment: You may have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server

Comment: An idea where to start looking: if you do a `select distinct(firstname)` with an `each` clause and `left outter join`  each row to `select  lastname ` for the given `firstname` in the `each` this would give you a firstname column with multiple lastname columns following

Comment: There might be a way to do it similiar to `select firstname, lastname from table group by firstname`

Comment: It seems like what you're trying to do might be better achieved from the UI/Display layer.  You're going to have to write an interesting query to explicitly ignore only the second occurrence of a First Name.  It's completely possible but probably easier to write (and possibly faster, performance-wise) from the front end.

Comment: The problem is that both the columns are in a same table, if I want to group by with first name I am not able to selecting last name:(

Comment: How to do it with front end? Kalmino

Comment: It depends on what language you're writing your front end in.  The below is the general idea I would use; you'll have to find the syntax to do it in your front-end language (C#, Java, HTML, ASP.net, etc..?).  Personally, I would add a "ORDER BY FirstName" clause to your SQL to group all the FirstNames and then, on the front end, store the first First Name in a variable, output it and the LastName and then loop to the next row.  If it's FirstName is the same as the variable you saved, don't output it; if it's different, output it and overwrite your FirstName variable to the new name.

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with the lag() function that Andomar supplied below but, if you wanted to keep your logic in SQL, give it a try; seems like it might be a neat tool to know about.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually I am using gridview control in asp.net, so making my output customize will be tricky :(

Comment: Thank you everybody for their time:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`row_number()` analytic function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to determine if the last name has changed:

```
select  case
        when row_number() over (partition by FirstName 
                                order by FirstName, LastName) = 1 
            then FirstName
        else ''
        end as FirstName
,       LastName
from    YourTable
order by
        YourTable.FirstName
,       LastName
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d214/7/0)

Comment: That works awesome.. thank you so much, but the problem with me is that I have SQL Server 2008 on which lag function is not working

Comment: Can you suggest me any other way without lag function?

Comment: Edited to use `row_number()`, does that work in 2008?

Comment: Yeah...yippiiiii.......that works just fine..Thank you so much.. I really appreciate you time and efforts...Thank you