# Recursive Function for MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, recursion, recursive-query

I need to write a recursive function to get the references from `table B` and combine in a field in `table A`.

**Table A:**

```
ID   Name      Reference
1    Item A 
2    Item B 
3    Item C
```

**Table B:**

```
ID   Parent_ID   Reference
1    1           ABC
2    1           DEF
3    2           GHI
```

**Expected result:**

```
ID   Name      Reference
1    Item A     ABCDEF
2    Item B     GHI
3    Item C
```

Comment: Where is the recursion? What should it be fro b and c?

Comment: Please add the expected output

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a query with group\_concat in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Comment: My expected results are: the reference of Item A (the ID 1 in table A) "ABCDEF" and for Item B "GHI". The recursion will be to get the references, and it should be recursive because table B can get up to 50 times.

Comment: This isn't recursion.   Recursion is when a parent of one item can be the child of another, but since you are joining two tables, you can only go one level deep.

Comment: It's not duplicated from the other question, because in that case he just wanted to make a select and see the results, in my case I need to update the field in database. I believe that the better way to do it is using recursion, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any recursion here:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      Name VARCHAR(10) ,
      Reference VARCHAR(100)
    )
DECLARE @b TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      ParentID INT ,
      Reference VARCHAR(3)
    )

INSERT  INTO @a
VALUES  ( 1, 'Item A', NULL ),
        ( 2, 'Item B', NULL ),
        ( 3, 'Item C', NULL )

INSERT  INTO @b
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 'ABC' ),
        ( 2, 1, 'DEF' ),
        ( 3, 2, 'GHI' )


UPDATE  a
SET     Reference = ca.data
FROM    @a a
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    
                   (            SELECT  b.Reference
                                FROM    @b b
                                WHERE   a.ID = b.ParentID
                                ORDER BY ID
                      FOR       XML PATH('') ,
                                    TYPE
                   ).value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS DATA
                    ) ca

SELECT  *
FROM    @a
```

Output:

```
ID  Name    Reference
1   Item A  ABCDEF
2   Item B  GHI
3   Item C  NULL
```

Comment: That's a great idea, I haven't thought about it. I'll try it and see if it works.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the answer, this is a real better way to do it - instead of recursive function. Thank you again :)

Comment: Just one more question, how can I put a comma between the result? Just realized that it would be better to read if it was like this: "ABC, DEF" - I mean, I know that I just need to put it after the select, but there is any way to avoid it in the last one? So it would look "ABC, DEF" instead of "ABC, DEF,"

Comment: SELECT ',' + b.Reference
                                FROM    @b b