# Multiple Id Values from multiple rows to single value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks something like the folowing

```
ID     LINE_NUMBER  CODE          DATA
39311   1           AXFP-20090    A
39311   2           AXFP-20227    B
39311   3           AXFP-20067    B
39311   4           AXFP-20337    B
39311   5           AXFP-20081    B
39311   6           AXFP-20048    B
39311   7           AXFP-20025    B
39311   8           AXFP-22371    B
39311   9           AXFP-20176    B
39311   10          AXFP-20278    B
39311   11          AXFP-21838    B
39311   14          AXFP-92035    C
41681   1           AXFP-99999    A
41681   2           AXFP-58229    A
41681   3           AXFP-51166    A
41681   5           AXFP-21848    C
41681   6           AXFP-58191    C
41681   7           AXFP-61481    C
41681   8           AXFP-21757    A
41681   9           AXFP-32704    C
41681   10          AXFP-60037    B
41681   11          AXFP-21849    B
41681   12          AXFP-34021    C
41681   13          AXFP-34072    C
```

I need to combine the data for each id into one row. To hold the line number, code and Data in the following format

[image]

Anyone have any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: You need a group concat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

```
select  ID     ,
Data=Stuff((SELECT ' ' + CAST(LINE_NUMBER  as VARCHAR(255)) + ')' + CODE  +  ' ' + DATA  FROM t t1 WHERE t1.ID =t.ID        
 FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '' )
from t
GROUP BY ID
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54f8b/3)