# Sql Joining maptables and separating results with comma

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables. I have connected it using a query, but I would like to separate results with comma in one line instead of showing result on different line.

**1st table**

```
 ProgrammeId | Name
====================
1 |Software Engineering                                         
2 | Game Design
```

**2nd table**

```
 CoordinatorId| CoordinatorName
====================
1 |Bob                                         
2 | Ted
```

**3d table**

```
 ProgrammeId| CoordinatorId
====================
1 | 1                                         
1 | 2
2 | 1
```

That is a query.

```
 SELECT a.ProgrammeId, a.Name, c.NameCoordinator
FROM Programme a
--Joining maptable for Programme and Coordinator
INNER JOIN ProgrammeCoordinators b
ON a.ProgrammeId = b.ProgrammeId
INNER JOIN Coordinator c
ON b.CoordinatorId = c.CoordinatorId
```

Output will be something like that:

```
 ProgrammeId| Name | CoordinatorName
==================================
1 | Software Engineer | Bob                                        
1 | Software Engineer  | Ted
2 | Game Design | Ted
```

How can I separate to show this:

```
1 | Software Engineer | Bob, Ted
```

Comment: do you really need a comma? wouldn't an xml document do better, like this: `<coordinators><c>Bob</c><c>Ted</c></coordinators>`?

Comment: this is often referred to another way, why doesnt sql server have a group_concat like mysql. well good news. that question has been asked already and answered http://stackoverflow.com/a/5981860/1158842. perhaps a better example for you is http://stackoverflow.com/a/17591536/1158842

Answer (score 0):

If your Name is length  100 :

```
SELECT a.ProgrammeId, a.Name(Name,' ',100), c.NameCoordinator
FROM Programme a
--Joining maptable for Programme and Coordinator
INNER JOIN ProgrammeCoordinators b
ON a.ProgrammeId = b.ProgrammeId
INNER JOIN Coordinator c
ON b.CoordinatorId = c.CoordinatorId
```

Comment: What is "Titel"? Does not work like this.

Comment: sorry, its should be the  name of column (i edited my post)

Comment: You can add    -- CoordinatorName(CoordinatorName,' ',100)--        and have    all columns  aligned to the  right. Don't forget to customize the length.