# convert two columns into two comma separated lists in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am facing an issue to convert two different columns into two comma separated lists. I am having two columns with Name Bachelor and Masters which are holding different digress. Now I need to convert both of them into comma separate lists

```
create table #user (Bachelor varchar(25),Masters varchar(25))

insert into #user (Bachelor,Masters) values ('B.A','M.A')
insert into #user (Bachelor,Masters) values ('B.E','MCA')
insert into #user (Bachelor,Masters) values ('B.Tech','M.Tech')
```

I need two columns which are having comma separate values as below.

```
Bachelor         Master

B.A,B.E,B.Tech   M.A,MCA,M.Tech
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Why `mysql` tag if you are searchig sor an SQL-server solution?

Comment: Thanks Jens to point out this thing. You are right I need the solution in Sql server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a query with group\_concat in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Comment: In this post Stuff function is used and do we need to use the Stuff function for both columns differently or is there any-other best way to do this?

Comment: @HarshGupta - your last comment should go under the posted answer that used the `Stuff()` function not this general comments area. Poster will be alerted in doing so.

Comment: Jen, the users assign a tag in a manner consonant with their grasp of the problem space in general and the problem in particular.  That should set the stage and the tone for any attendant subsequent help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  STUFF((
    SELECT
      ',' + Bachelor
    FROM #user
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, '') AS Bachelor,
  STUFF((
    SELECT
      ',' + Masters
    FROM #user
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, '') AS Masters
```