# T-SQL query append columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a T-SQL query that returns a result of two rows with the same contact name but in one of the columns is different:

```
Contact Name   BuildingID    ClassID
------------------------------------
XXXX              720         3505
XXXX              720         3650
```

I need to combine both `ClassID` values into the `ClassID` column like this:

```
Contact Name   BuildingID    ClassID
----------------------------------------
XXXX              720        3505;3650
```

Comment: That's a SQL Anti Pattern.  One field should contain one value.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a query with group\_concat in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server) --- Concatenating multiple values into a single field in a view is a pretty common requirements. Some RDBMS have built in functionality (Group_Concat in MySQL or string_agg in Oracle, for instance). With SQL Server you to use `stuff()` and `cross apply` to get the job done. Check out that link and it should get you close to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this using stuff and xml Path

```
SELECT ContactName, BuildingID,
   STUFF((SELECT ','+CONVERT(varchar(20),classid) FROM Contacts where contactname= c.ContactName and BuildingId = c.BuildingID
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS ClassId
FROM Contacts C
Group by ContactName, BuildingId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #XX
(
    ContactName VARCHAR(10) ,
    BuildingId INT,
    ClassId INT
)


INSERT INTO #XX VALUES ('XXXX',720,3505)
INSERT INTO #XX VALUES ('XXXX',720,3650)


SELECT DISTINCT ContactName,BuildingId,STUFF((
                SELECT  ';' + CAST(ClassId AS VARCHAR(10))
                FROM #XX FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') AS ClassId
                FROM #XX
```