# Data merge in SQL

Tags: sql-server, merge

I tried the below query to display data

```
select  e.Name,ic.Code,t1.pyear,t1.pmonth,t2.Amount     
from t1 
inner join t2 on t2.id=t1.id
inner join t3  on t3.Code=t2.Code
inner join t4 e on t4.employeeindex=t1.employeeindex 
where t1.pyear=2016 and t1.pmonth=1

union all 

select  e.Name,ic.Code,t1.pyear,t1.pmonth,t2.Amount     
from t1 
inner join t2 on t2.id=t1.id
inner join t3  on t3.Code=t2.Code
inner join t4 e on t4.employeeindex=t1.employeeindex 
where t1.pyear=2016 and t1.pmonth=2
```

and the data i am getting is like this-

```
scode amount month year       e_name
  abc     3847    1    2016    john
  ABC     20938   2    2016    john
  XYZ     2838    1    2016    david
  XYZ     29384   2    2016    david
```

now i want to display data like this

```
 s_code  amount1 amount2  month1  month2   year  e_name
   abc     3847    20938    1       2       2016    john
   xyz     2838    29384    1       2       2016    david
```

any solution ?

Comment: Both sides of the `UNION` look the same to me, which therefore can't explain your current output.  Also, bad idea naming your columns `index`.  That's a keyword in most SQL databases.

Comment: can you provide sample tables, please?

Comment: i mention here as t1 actual in my side there is tables name ..

Comment: @DheerajSharma you mean tables column or table name ?

Comment: sample data from where you got your result after query!

Comment: i think after this line "and the data i am getting is like this-" is data what i get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## edit

You could try to use cte. The following is just an example, adjust the column names by yourself because it's a bit of a mess

```
WITH unionall AS (
    select ic.Code, t2.Amount, t1.pmonth, t1.pyear, e.Name
    from t1 
    inner join t2 on t2.id=t1.id
    inner join t3  on t3.Code=t2.Code
    inner join t4 e on t4.employeeindex=t1.employeeindex 
    where t1.pyear=2016 and (t1.pmonth=1 OR t2.pmonth=2)
)

SELECT r1.scode, r1.amount as amount1, r2.amount as amount2
FROM unionall r1 inner join unionall r2 on r1.scode = r2.scode
```

### -----------------------

If you know for sure that for each s_code there are 2 months (or at least a costant number) you could easily make a join on itself and select all the values with an alias, like so:

`SELECT r1.scode, r1.amount as amount1, r2.amount as amount2 [...more fields...]
FROM result r1 inner join result r2 on r1.scode = r2.scode [...many joins as many months...]`

If there can be multiple month that you don't know, i would probably do what on mysql is a [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Basically, you group by scode and then, in the same field, there's a list separated values. Too bad you can't do a group_concat in SQLServer, but there are workaround guides around the web

[How to make a query with group_concat in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Comment: i did not understand please more specify

Comment: What you ask can be easily achieved with a simple inner join. If you don't understand it, i suggest you to read a few guides before!