# Combine multiple rows into one row with sequence column SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please help. I'm trying to concatenate the notes by `SequenceNo` and group by `RecControlID` and `EmpNo`.

Before:

[Before](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2oJ2_mmKuEKSVRBM2ZWaGNDOUk/view?usp=sharing)

After:

[After](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2oJ2_mmKuEKX3RsdzI5Y1g1am8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Click the links for the images.  I do not know how to embed the pics.

Comment: How did this problem come about?Why not just select the Max(Note) if they are going to be duplicated

Comment: The actual notes are not duplicated, only the example. I used the same sentence(s) to save time.

Comment: Caps lock doesn't help clarify your question....

Comment: I've updated the 'After' removing the Sequence column.

Comment: This will help, but you're going to have to find a way to distinguish between sets of groups: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server