# Select all duplicate values group by row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table as

```
Building    Stairs
A           Two
B.          Three
C.          Two
```

I need output as

```
A,C.     Two
B.       Three
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a query with group\_concat in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Comment: you can do with STUFF function, FOR XML clause. Search this forum and I'm sure you'll find.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  STUFF((    SELECT ', ' + b.Building
            FROM #table b
            WHERE b.Stairs = a.Stairs               
            FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '' ) AS Building,
    Stairs
FROM #table a
```