# data result group by date in frontend view html in codeinginter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, group-by

I have table like this. The table result order by date.
I'm using codeigniter framework. 
[image]

I want to print it out above result like below image.
[image]

Today, Yesterday can be display using helper function.

Model

```
function getData(){
  $this->db->order_by('date','desc');
  return $this->db->get('table')->result();
}
```

Controller

```
function index(){
  $this->load->model('data_model');
  $this->data['result'] = $this->data_model->getData();

  $this->load->view('dat_view', $this->data);
}
```

View

```
<div>
<?php
if($result){
  $date ='';
  foreach($result as $row){

     if(!$date){
       $date = $row->date; 
     }else{
       if($date != $row->date){
         $date = $row->date;
       }
     }

     echo 'Date : ' . $date;
     echo '<li>'.$row->title.'</li>';

  }
}
?>
</div>
```

above code display like below

Date : 2017-11-28
   1. Some title A

Date : 2017-11-28
   1. Some title B

Date : 2017-11-28
   1. Some title C

Please help me to group this by any function or array or other.

Comment: Add GROUP_CONCAT in SELECT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Comment: The thing is I need to list the records,  table description column got article data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetching data ordered by date which is fine in view you just need to add some conditional logic to show date only once for same date records

```
<div>
    <?php
    if ($result) {
        $date = false;
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            if ($row->date != $date) {
                echo 'Date : ' . $date;
                $date = $row->date;
            }
            echo '<li>' . $row->title . '</li>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

There is no need to use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) because at some stage it might fail or you need to adjust some Mysql configuration due to character limitation.

> As per docs The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet

Or prepare your data in controller like each date array has collection of its title like

```
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[$row->date][] = $row->title;
}
```

this will produce an array like

```
array(
'2017-11-28' => array('some title a','some title b'),
'2017-11-29' => array('some title a','some title b')
)
```

Pass this $data to your view and loop through your array as

```
<div>
    <?php
    foreach ($data as $date => $titles) {
        echo 'Date : ' . $date;
        foreach ($titles as $title) {
            echo '<li>' . $title . '</li>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: it works well,  I like to use second method, but Witch one is the faster ?

Comment: @SampathSriAnuradha Performance wise first approach is better than second one because it has only single loop to show the desired data while as compare to second approach it involves 3 loops

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid Thanks. yeah, first one more simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you select query... apply it in your code accordingly...

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(title),date
FROM table_name GROUP BY date ORDER BY date
```

Comment: The How can I  fetch data in the view.