# SQL Vertical Table to Horizontal Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a table that contains multiple employee's assigned to a desk. I need help figuring out a way to show all of the desks for the employee.

Currently, I am using this query which seems close but it is pulling every desk.

I would like it to look something like this:

```
|fk_employee| fk_desk  |
|3          | 1000,1001|
```

Using SQL 2012

```
select fk_employee,
    stuff((SELECT distinct ', ' + cast(fk_desk as varchar(10))
    from dat_desk_employee e
    where e.fk_employee = e.fk_employee
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
from dat_desk_employee e
group by fk_employee
order by fk_employee asc
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your desired result and your DBMS (version included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used same alias for both,main and stuff query.

> ```
> create table dat_desk_employee (fk_desk int, fk_employee int);
> insert into dat_desk_employee values
> (1000, 2),(1000, 10),(1000, 23),(1000, 34),(1000, 55),
> (1001, 3),(1001, 10),(1001, 23),(1001, 35),(1001, 60);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 10 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select fk_employee,
>        stuff((SELECT distinct ', ' + cast(fk_desk as varchar(10))
>               from dat_desk_employee t
>               where t.fk_employee = e.fk_employee
>        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') fk_desks
> from dat_desk_employee e
> group by fk_employee
> order by fk_employee asc 
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> fk_employee | fk_desks   
> ----------: | :----------
>           2 |  1000      
>           3 |  1001      
>          10 |  1000, 1001
>          23 |  1000, 1001
>          34 |  1000      
>          35 |  1001      
>          55 |  1000      
>          60 |  1001
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=458a19182a34c8c19f45c77a9243a8b0)*

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (fk_desk VARCHAR(100), fk_employee VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('1000', '1')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('1001', '1')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('1000', '2')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('1001', '2')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('1002', '2')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('1003', '3')

SELECT 
    fk_employee
    , STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + T.fk_desk
          FROM @Table T WHERE A.fk_employee = T.fk_employee
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as fk_desk
FROM @Table A
GROUP BY A.fk_employee
```

and this have been answered on this question before:
[How to make a query with group_concat in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)