# How to find all those authors wrote a paper together?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I write an SQL query to find those authors who has co-authored some paper together.

schema :

```
Authors (
    authorID,
    firstName,
);
Papers (
    paperID,
    title,
);
PaperbyAuthor (
    authorID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Authors,
    paperID FOREIGN KEY  REFERENCES Papers
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will list all the Authors with their PaperID for Authors that have worked on a paper together.

```
SELECT PA.paperID, GROUP_CONCAT(A.firstName separator ',') FROM PaperbyAuthor PA
INNER JOIN Authors A ON PA.authorID = A.authorID
WHERE paperID IN (SELECT paperID FROM PaperbyAuthor PA
GROUP BY paperID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

You can also join the table with Papers if you need to see the title of the paper.

Comment: Yes. You can use group concat. If you want it in separate columns then you need to consider a scenario where more than 2 authors have worked on a paper.

Comment: @clinomanic query returned as `GROUP_CONCAT is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: Are you using mysql or sqlserver? The question is tagged with both and I didn't realize that earlier. GROUP_CONCAT is only for mysql

Comment: i am using sqlserver

Comment: Take a look at this post to see how to do this in sqlserver. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

This will give you every pair of authors twice: if John and Joe co-write a paper, there will be entries for

```
CoAuthor1   CoAuthor2   JointPapers 
JOHN        JOE         1
JOE         JOHN        1
```

The code is:

```
SELECT
    a1.firstName AS CoAuthor1,
    a2.firstName AS CoAuthor2,
    l.JointPapers
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        pba1.authorID AS CoAuthorID1,
        pba2.authorID AS CoAuthorID2,
        COUNT(*) AS JointPapers
    FROM
        PaperByAuthor AS pba1
    LEFT JOIN
        PaperByAuthor AS pba2
    ON
        pba1.paperID = pba2.paperID
    GROUP BY
        pba1.authorID,
        pba2.authorID
    ) AS l  
LEFT JOIN
    Authors AS a1
ON
    l.CoAuthorID1 = a1.authorID
LEFT JOIN
    Authors AS a2
ON
    l.CoAuthorID2 = a2.authorID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the authors who co-authored a specific paper, try:

```
SELECT a.authorID, a.firstName
FROM Authors a
INNER JOIN PaperbyAuthor pa ON pa.authorID = a.authorID
INNER JOIN Papers p ON p.paperID = pa.paperID
WHERE p.paperID = 1000;
```

Change the value 1000 to ID of the paper that you want. If you want to find the paper by title, change the last line to:

```
WHERE p.title = 'The Best Paper';
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wanted. I believe OP was asking for a list of authors that have worked on the same paper together. This returns the authors that have worked on a specific paper.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for pairs of authors?

```
select distinct min(authorID), max(authorID)
from PapersByAuthor pa
group by paperID
having count(authorID) = 2
```