# Add two nvarchar columns using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackQuestion]
(
    [ID] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Product_Id] [BIGINT] NULL,
    [Quantity] [DECIMAL](18, 6) NULL,
    [Description] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_StackQuestion] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
```

Demo data

```
INSERT [dbo].[StackQuestion] ([ID], [Product_Id], [Quantity], [Description]) 
VALUES (1, 10, CAST(50.000000 AS Decimal(18, 6)), N'Description1'), 
       (2, 20, CAST(10.000000 AS Decimal(18, 6)), N'StackDesc'),
        3, 10, CAST(10.000000 AS Decimal(18, 6)), N'Descrip2')
GO
```

So basically I need to group those columns by product id and sum their total quantity. And I can do that by a simple query such as

```
SELECT 
    MAX(ID) AS LastID, Product_Id, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity 
FROM 
    stackquestion
GROUP BY 
    Product_Id
```

The point is how to get total description of all items in that group. My description column needs to contain all descriptions in that group (SUM of nvarchar)

Output should be something like this:

[image: Desc]

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: @P.Salmon 2008 and newer

Comment: The solution for SQL Server 2008 involves `stuff` and `for xml`. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591536/50552, or Google for "SQL Server group_concat".

Comment: I can probably find more duplicates if this isn't enough :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is SQL Server 2017 or SQL Server Vnext, SQL Azure you can use string_agg as below

```
SELECT 
    MAX(ID) AS LastID, Product_Id, SUM(Quantity) AS 
    Quantity,string_agg(concat( [Description]), CHAR(13)) AS Description

FROM 
    stackquestion
GROUP BY 
    Product_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

According to @Andomar the one of solutions would be query like [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql)

```
SELECT 
    MAX(ID) AS LastID, Product_Id, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity,
    Description = STUFF((SELECT ',' + [Description] 
                         FROM stackquestion c 
                         WHERE c.Product_Id = stackquestion.Product_Id 
                         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM 
    stackquestion
GROUP BY
    Product_Id
```

Comment: I'd like to add this is the go-to kind of solution prior to SQL Server 2017 which finally saw the rise of STRING_AGG function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

More than you want but has the data you want

```
SELECT ID, Product_Id, Quantity
     , SUM(Quantity) over (partition by Product_Id) AS SumQuantity 
FROM stackquestion
ORDER BY 
    Product_Id, ID
```

Comment: Typo in ORDER.. Thanks