# SQL Combine multiple rows into one column and get name from Ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-concatenation

Consider a database table `connectouser` holding two IDs:

```
 connectouser
compID    coopID
   1         1
   1         2
   1         3
   2         1
   2         2
```

Consider another database table `coop` holding two IDs:

```
coop
ID   Name
1     ABC
2     DEF
3     GHJ
```

I want to the following output :

```
Result
compID   coopname
1        ABC,DEF,GHJ
2        ABC,DEF
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a query with group\_concat in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

The question was tagged MySQL for this answer.

This is a group by and `group_concat()`:

```
select cu.compId, group_concat(co.name order by co.id) as coopnames
from connectouser cu join
     coop co
     on cu.coopID = co.ID
group by cu.compId;
```

In SQL Server, you can do:

```
select cu.compId,
       stuff( (select ',' + co.name
               from coop co
               where cu.coopID = co.ID
               order by co.id
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as names
from connectouser cu;
```

The most recent version of SQL Server supports `string_agg()`, which is a much better approach.

Comment: it shows error `group_contact()` is not recognized built in function in sql

Comment: Just copy and paste the SQL @HatimRanapurwala .. The function is called `group_concat()` not `group_contact()`

Comment: sorry it was typing mistake 
it shows error `group_concat()` is not recognized built in function in sql

Comment: Or you are using a very old MySQL version or no MySQL at all which i believe is more likely @HatimRanapurwala ... Because "is not recognized built in function in sql " looks to me like a SQL Server error message.