# Looking for an efficient way of emulating LISTAGG(STRING_AGG) on Microsoft Analytics Platform System

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been tasked with migrating some **Oracle SQL** onto **Microsofts Analytics Platform System**.

The original Oracle code is basically as follows:

```
SELECT MyID,TO_CHAR(LISTAGG(ListValue)) MyValue
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MyID
```

`STRING_AGG` is not supported even in the latest release, and neither are any of the usual methods to achieve this.

Any ideas?

Comment: `neither are any of the usual methods to achieve this` ... yes they are.  [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server).

Comment: SQL Server 2016 added STRING_SPLIT. SQL Server 2017 added STRING_AGG. `STRING_AGG is not supported even in the latest release` that's wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with higher version then you can use [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :

```
SELECT MyID, STRING_AGG(ListValue, ',') AS MyValue
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MyID;
```

However, the same could also be achieved with xml method which is older & help with low version SQL.

```
SELECT MyID, STUFF ( (SELECT ', ' +CAST(t1.ListValue AS VARCHAR(255)) -- Neglate conversion if unnecessary 
                      FROM MyTable t1
                      WHERE t1.MyID = t.MyID
                      FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 1, ''
                   ) AS MyValue
FROM MyTable t
GROUP BY MyID;
```