# Group by contact - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to merge or concat columns  based on two column values.

```
ID          ID_1        Name    Value   ID_3
NULL          1          A        x      NULL
NULL          1          B        x      NULL
NULL          1          A        y      NULL
NULL          2          C        p      NULL
3           NULL         A        x      NULL
3           NULL         B        x      NULL
3           NULL         A        y      NULL
4           NULL         C        p      NULL
```

Expected Result :

```
ID          ID_1        Name    Value   ID_3
NULL          1          AB       x      NULL
NULL          1          A        y      NULL
NULL          2          C        p      NULL
3            NULL        AB       x      NULL
3            NULL        A        y      NULL
4            NULL        C        p      NULL
```

For Id_1 , I want to concat Name but only where value column has same value.
Similarly for ID_2 as well.

Comment: **see this Answer** [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331640/how-to-write-the-t-sql-string-agg-function/51339959#51339959](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331640/how-to-write-the-t-sql-string-agg-function/51339959#51339959)

Answer (score 3):

If it is `SQL Server 2017` you can try to use `string_agg` function.

```
select ID,ID_1,string_agg(Name, '') 'Name',Value,ID_3
 from T 
group by ID,ID_1,Value,ID_3
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/20dad/6)

**[Results]**:

```
|     ID |   ID_1 | Name | Value |   ID_3 |
|--------|--------|------|-------|--------|
| (null) |      1 |   AB |     x | (null) |
| (null) |      1 |    A |     y | (null) |
| (null) |      2 |    C |     p | (null) |
|      3 | (null) |   AB |     x | (null) |
|      3 | (null) |    A |     y | (null) |
|      4 | (null) |    C |     p | (null) |
```

If your `SQL Server` version lower than 2017, you can try to use *with FOR XML and PATH*.

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  ID_1,
  STUFF((
    SELECT Name
    FROM T
    WHERE 
        Value = t1.Value 
    and 
        (ID = t1.ID or ID_1 = t1.ID_1)
     FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,0,'') AS 'Name',
    Value,
    ID_3
FROM T t1
group by ID,ID_1,Value,ID_3
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/20dad/37)

Answer (score 0):

If you have at most two rows that need to be aggregated, then a simpler method is:

```
select id, id_1,
       (case when min(name) = max(name) then min(name)
             else min(name) + max(name)
        end) as names
       value, id_3
from t
group by id, id_1, value, id_3;
```

If you don't know that there are only up to two matches, then you need to do a more sophisticated string aggregation.