# Combine Record by Group SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:

```
--------------------------------
oGroup      oValue
--------------------------------
1           Us
1           Uk
1           In
2           Ch
2           Ar
```

My question is, how can I combine some records with the same `oGroup` value? The result should be:

```
---------------------------------
oGroup      oValue
---------------------------------
1           Us, Uk, In
2           Ch, Ar
```

Please advise. 
Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Comment: Otherwise you can just copy this one :)


`SELECT DISTINCT A.oGroup, 
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT ','+B.oValue  AS [text()]
            FROM #TableA B
            WHERE B.oGroup = A.oGroup
            ORDER BY B.oGroup
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [oValue]
FROM #TableA A`

Comment: @MohamedAzizi, please put it on answer. This is great!

Comment: @Haminteu I can't because someone flagged this question as a duplicate therefore I can't add an answer only comments