# List Enum String in HTML/PHP Dropdown with values from 2 MSSQL tables

Tags: php, html, sql-server, dropdown

I want to list a string in my dropdown selection like:

Name | IntervallNumber | Intervall

This 3 values in the string need to populated from 2 MSSQL tables. Now in deep I explain the tables and what results I want in the dropdown as a string.

This is table 1:

```
+-------------+------+
| PK_Table1_ID| Name |
+-------------+------+
|     1       | Name1|
|     2       | Name2|
|     3       | Name3|
+-------------+------+
```

table 2:

```
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+
| PK_Table2_ID | FK_Table1_ID | IntervallNumber | Intervall |
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+
|      1       |      2       |        1        |    168    |
|      2       |      2       |        2        |    336    |
|      3       |      2       |        3        |    500    |
|      4       |      2       |        4        |    672    |
|      5       |      2       |        5        |    840    |
|      6       |      2       |        6        |    1000   |
|      7       |      3       |        1        |    168    |
|      8       |      3       |        2        |    500    |
|      9       |      3       |        3        |    1000   |
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

I think I need multiple SQL `SELECT` statements and merge them together to a string, to populate it for my dropdown.

Maybe something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT Name FROM table1";
$sql2 = "SELECT IntervallNumber, Intervall 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE table1.PK_Table1_ID = table2.FK_Table1_ID";
$seperator = " | ";
$string = $sql . $seperator . $sql2;
```

The output string should look like in detail like:

```
echo "<option>" . $string . "</option>";
```

> first select option: "Name2 | 6 | 168,336,500,672,840,100"
>
> second select option: "Name3 | 3 | 168,500,100"

The 3rd value needs to be a string too.

The big problem is how to declare the MSSQL statements right and combine it to a enum only in the selction, not in SQL column, because the colums is integer and cant be take `nvarchar` with the `,`.

Any suggestions how I can solve this?

Comment: What is your SQL server version?

Comment: Its ususally a rule of thumb that there is always an SQL statement to replace merging two `SELECT`s. SQL querys are very powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try with this:

T-SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    A.name, 
    IntervallNumber = MAX(IntervallNumber),
    Intervall = STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), X.Intervall)
        FROM Table2 X
        WHERE B.FK_Table1_ID = X.FK_Table1_ID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM Table1 A
JOIN Table2 B ON A.PK_Table1_ID = B.FK_Table1_ID
GROUP BY B.FK_Table1_ID, A.name
```

Output:

```
Name2 6 168, 336, 500, 672, 840, 1000
Name3 3 168, 500, 1000
```

Notes:

Tested with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Perfect, thats what i was looking for. thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL you need will look something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name, ' | ', MAX(IntervallNumber), ' | ', GROUP_CONCAT(Intervall))
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.PK_Table1_ID = t2.FK_Table1_ID
GROUP BY t1.PK_Table1_ID
```

Edit: the above is `MySQL`, but should instead use something like [how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Comment: i tryed the code from the link but i get errors:

<pre>SELECT rop.PK_Table1_ID, rop.Name, ropp.IntervallNumber, Intervall = STUFF((
SELECT ',' + ropp.Intervall FROM Table2 ropp
WHERE rop.PK_Table1_ID = ropp.FK_Table1_ID
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM Table1 rop 
JOIN table2 ropp ON rop.PK_Table1_ID = ropp.FK_Table1_ID
ORDER BY rop.name<code>

Comment: That is why I said "will look something like this" and then linked to where to replace the GROUP_CONCAT, I'm sorry I'm not in a position to debug sql server at present

Comment: ok i see the problem the soultion is not for me usefull, becasue its only considered for sql based output results if the column would be a nvarchar but the last columns Intervall is a int, so i cant enum it inside her. so i need a soloution string combined in php

Answer (score 1):

Change this query

```
    $sql = "SELECT Name FROM table1";
  $sql2 = "SELECT IntervallNumber, Intervall 
  FROM table2 
 WHERE table1.PK_Table1_ID = table2.FK_Table1_ID";
```

To

```
 $sql = "SELECT a.Name,b.IntervallNumber from table b LEFT JOIN table a on 
 a.PK_Table1_ID = b.FK_Table1_ID WHERE a.PK_Table1_ID = b.FK_Table1_ID";
```

With this you can get the name and the interval number in the dropdown

Comment: ok and how i get the  column 'intervall' all the values with  same FK_Table1_ID enum as a result next to NAME and IntervallNumber in the dropdown ?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT a.Name + "|" + b.IntervallNumber+"|" b.Intervall from table b LEFT JOIN table a on 
 a.PK_Table1_ID = b.FK_Table1_ID WHERE a.PK_Table1_ID = b.FK_Table1_ID";