# How combine multiple cells into a single row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am trying to convert work done MS Excel into t-sql code. Column A is my index. I need to combine the values associate with index =1 in column C, each separated by a soft break.

In MS Excel I achieve this by placing this function in  cell C2=*IF(A2<>A1,B2,C1 & CHAR(10) & B2)* and *=IF(A2<>A3,1,0)*.

[image]

The combined functions on column C will concatenate of the values in column B, as the index in column 1 match. The function in column D will compare the values in column C until it finds an unique value. In cell D5, notice values from B2:B5 has been concatenated into a single cell.

If filter the worksheet where the values in column D =1, then I am able to get the desired result.

[image]

How can I make this happened in SQL?

Comment: `[colors] attribute`?

Comment: This is the job of a application...soft breaks?

Comment: what determines the order of your data? Currently, there is no way to guarantee the return of the results to be deterministic

Comment: @user2404597
In excel this can be achieve using [ALT]+[ENTER]

Comment: @scsimon 

The data will be sorted by No prior to being loaded in SQL.

Comment: that's all fine and dandy, but once it's in sql server it becomes ordered despite *looking* ordered. select without an order by statement doesn't guarantee the results will be returned int he same order. Read this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/ which means the accepted answer won't always work even though it may seem to on that small data size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an elegant solution, but it get the job done. Please feel free to improve on it.

---

### Note:

Carriage return char(13) and line feed char(10) will not work in SSMS. You will be able to see the desired outcome in platforms such as SSRS or Tableau.

```
select distinct no, 
    color = 
    Stuff((select char(13) + char(10) +t1.color 
    from test t1
    where 
    t1.No = t2.No
    for xml path (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'), 1, 1,'')
from test t2
```

**SSMS**

```
  no    color
   1    blue red pink  yellow
   2    blue  red  pink 
   3    yellow
```

**Tableau**

```
  no    color
   1    blue
        red
        pink 
        yellow
   2    blue 
        red 
        pink
   3    yellow
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, with a caveat:

```
DECLARE @ TABLE (No int, color VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @(No, color) values

--No  color
(1  ,'blue'),
(1  ,'red'),
(1  ,'pink'),
(1  ,'yellow'),
(2  ,'blue'),
(2  ,'red'),
(2  ,'pink'),
(3  ,'yellow')

SELECT IIF(rn = 1,CAST(No as CHAR(1)), '') AS No, color
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY No ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn,
No, color
FROM @
) _
```

The caveat is what the comment by scsimon is getting at.  There is no guarantee that SQL will return the rows in the order you posted.

Comment: Why does your script end in "_"?

Comment: Last, what you are suggestion is creating '' where rn != 1. 
I need to concatenate all the strings where No =1, No=2 & No = 3 into a cell. In other words, I need to use something like char(13) and char(10). 
I tried to modified your code, but I did not provide the desire results.

Comment: your expected results didn't specify this @user716255 and in this case, you need to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server