# How to retrieve data from a single column in one table with different conditions(dates)

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table here:

```
Salesid   Total      Date
----------------------------
   1       100    2018-11-24
   2       200    2018-11-25
   3       300    2018-11-26
   4       400    2018-11-27
   5       500    2018-11-28
```

I'm having a difficulty retrieving separately **each total** for **each day** with assigned aliases and in a single query so it would appear like:

```
Day1   Day2   Day3   Day4   Day5
100    200    300    400    500
```

I have tried various queries but most of them yield an error

> "Subquery returns multiple rows"

Comment: I think it is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591536/6351894 : `maskdetail = STUFF(sub_query)`

Comment: What `RDBMS` you are using? `Sql` just language..

Comment: @dwir182 I'm actually using MySQL i forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the use of pivot if its available in the database you are using. Otherwise you can opt for a query structure as follows

```
select MAX(case when salesid=1 then total end) as day1
      ,MAX(case when salesid=2 then total end) as day2
      .....
  from table
```