# Getting all distinct values and sorting them by hour

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
ID    TimeStamp    CarNumber
1    2018\12\03 14:05:32    433
2    2018\12\03 14:13:52    420
3    2018\12\03 14:55:14    433
4    2018\12\03 15:12:03    420
5    2018\12\03 16:15:55    570
```

My desired output is a list of each car number in each hour of the day:

```
Hour       CarNumbers
0          0
...
14         433, 420
15         420
16         570
...
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 so I can't use string_agg(). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you can find something here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Comment: for xml path can be used!!!

Comment: I've been playing with for xml for a while, haven't found a way yet.

Comment: Should it be querying for only 1 day, or should it also group by & output the date? And do all 24 hours need to be in the result, regardless if the data is missing some hours?

Comment: @LukStorms For 1 day ( `where TimeStamp between 0:00 and 23:59` ), optionally grouped, if data is missing it's ok if the row is just skipped (all that not that important, I just need the numbers for each hour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get counts for all the hours, you'll need to left join to a list with all the hours.
And probably combined with the date of the timestamps if they span more than 1 date.

To substitute the missing `STRING_AGG` you could use the `FOR XML` trick.

**Example snippet:**

```
-- Using a table variable for demonstration
declare @Table table (id int primary key identity(1,1), [Timestamp] datetime, CarNumber int);

-- Sample data
insert into @Table ([Timestamp], CarNumber) values
('2018-12-03 14:05:32', 433),
('2018-12-03 14:13:52', 420),
('2018-12-03 14:55:14', 433),
('2018-12-03 15:12:03', 420),
('2018-12-03 16:15:55', 570),
('2018-12-09 14:00:00', 999);

-- Query
WITH RCTE_HOURS AS
(
  select 0 as [Hour] 
  union all
  select [Hour] + 1
  from RCTE_HOURS
  where [Hour] < 23
)
SELECT h.[Hour],
 COALESCE(STUFF((
   SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CarNumber) 
   FROM @Table t2 
   WHERE CAST(t2.[Timestamp] AS DATE) = d.[Date]
     AND DATEPART(HOUR, t2.[Timestamp]) = h.[Hour]
     AND CarNumber IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY CarNumber
   ORDER BY MIN(t2.[Timestamp])
   FOR XML PATH ('')
   ), 1, 2, ''),'0') AS CarNumbers
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT CAST([Timestamp] AS DATE) AS [Date]
  FROM @Table
  WHERE CAST([Timestamp] AS DATE) = CAST('2018-12-03' AS DATE)
) AS d
CROSS JOIN RCTE_HOURS h
ORDER BY d.[Date], h.[Hour];
```

**Returns:**

```
Hour CarNumbers
---- ---------- 
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
9    0
10   0
11   0
12   0
13   0
14   433, 420
15   420
16   570
17   0
18   0
19   0
20   0
21   0
22   0
23   0
```

Comment: `CONCAT` is an sql server 2012+ function. `VALUES` is also not supported as I see.

Comment: @user2979612 I replaced the CONCAT with a `+` concatination, and the VALUES with a Common Table Expression.  A pitty that CONCAT isn't in 2008, because it has the benefits that NULL's are ignored & INT's are implicitly casted.

Comment: Thank you, this query works with some tables. However, it does not work with big data tables (the same thing with 200k+ rows). It returns a `Timeout Expired` error. I'm currently trying to work around it, but if you have a solution I'll very much appreciate.

Comment: Without knowing what primary keys or indexes on those tables? I rather not bother myself by guessing.  But I solved a similar question like this by suggesting to load data into a #temporary table with a combined primary key that would benefit the speed of the SQL. F.e. `create table #tmpCars (dt date, hr int, carNumber int not null, primary key (dt, hr));`. Then select the data you need into that temp table. Then change the SQL so it uses that temp table and joins on those fields directly (without using CAST of DATEPART like in the current SQL).

Comment: And then while you're using a temporary table, might as well create a temp table for those hour numbers, and cross join to that temp table instead of using that Recursive CTE.

Comment: Correction, a primairy key on `(dt, hr)` would give errors on duplicates. So it should be a non-unique index on `(dt, hr)` I guess.  Anyway, the point is that a linking to a table mostly performs better if you do it directly on indexed fields, instead of joining on transformations of those indexed fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   DATEPART(HOUR, Timestamp), STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + carnumber 
              FROM tablename t1
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') carnumbers 
from tablename 
group by  DATEPART(HOUR, Timestamp) asc ;
```

Comment: `missing FROM clause`