# Converting n columns to delimited string from text only subquery

Tags: sql-server

This is for Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) - 13.0.4001.0

I have a rather annoying bit of data that needs to be converted into a comma separated string. My options are limited due to it being a 3rd party software that replaces text in my query and runs it. For example, I will write the following:

```
SELECT %myvalues% for xml path('')
```

Which then gets turned into:

```
SELECT 'test1','test2','test3'...'testn' for xml path('')
```

Which returns

```
test1test2test3...testn
```

This works, but it doesn't separate the text with commas or spaces. Here's the result I want:

```
test1, test2, test3, ... testn
```

The problem is, I can't control how it inserts the text. **I did find the STUFF function among a bunch of other solutions but none seem to work when I don't know the column names.**

For example, I get:

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

Comment: Sounds lie the problem here is the application, not the SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a query with group\_concat in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if this is the best way to do it, but I have had success with the following method:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('mytable', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE mytable; 
CREATE TABLE mytable ("@remove@'mylist', 'Ofannoying', 'comma', 'seperated values'" INT NULL);
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT c.Name FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.object_id WHERE o.name = 'mytable'), '''', ''), '@remove@', '')
```

Where my actual code looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ("@remove@#myvalues#" INT NULL);
```