# How to join the columns value in one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two columns relationship type and lives with 
like the following, I want all the relationship types values which has 'T' in lives with column in one column

```
+------------+---------+
|relationship|liveswith|
+------------+---------+
|A           |T        |
+------------+---------+
|B           |T        |
+------------+---------+
|C           |F        |
+------------+---------+
```

like this

```
+------------+---------+
|T           |F        |
+------------+---------+
|A B         |C        |
+------------+---------+
```

I tried using Pivot but it only gives me one values in T column. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Comment: How many possible values of `liveswith` are there?   Are T/F = True/False, or are they something else?

Comment: @TabAlleman it only has true and false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of for xml path('') and use STUFF as follows

```
 create table data(relationship varchar(10),liveswith varchar(10));

 insert into data values('A','T');
 insert into data values('B','T');
 insert into data values('C','F');

 with temp_output
     as (
       SELECT  a.liveswith
              ,STUFF((SELECT  '-' + relationship
                        FROM data a1
                       WHERE a1.liveswith=a.liveswith
                     ORDER BY relationship
                        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS listStr
         FROM data a
       GROUP BY a.liveswith
         )
select max(case when liveswith='T' then liststr end) as 'T'
      ,max(case when liveswith='F' then liststr end) as 'F'
 from temp_output  

+-----+---+
|  T  | F |
+-----+---+
| A-B | C |
+-----+---+
```

Comment: That's not the same format as the desired result in the question.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph can you explain the part where you union all I am not able to understand it

Comment: Yep, sure i used the with data() to simulate a table. I have updated my answer to make use of an actual table using create and insert scripts

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph ohh ok Thank you I got that it means my table

Answer (score 1):

You can pivot on true/false with case statements:

```
SELECT
string_agg(CASE WHEN liveswith THEN relationship ELSE '' END, ' ') AS T,
string_agg(CASE WHEN NOT liveswith THEN relationship ELSE '' END, ' ') AS F
FROM foobar;
```

Output:

```
  t   |  f
------+-----
 A B  |   C
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it says string_agg is not recognized as a built in function

Comment: Sorry, looks like it was implemented in sql server 2017: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sql-geek/2018/02/28/new-built-in-function-string_agg-sql-server-2017/