# Merge rows in SQL Server 2012 and have data separated by comma or minus

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT ALL
    RTrim(ARTICO.CODICE) AS [Cod.Ricambio],
    RTrim(ARTICO.DESCR) AS Descrizione,
    RTrim(ARTCLA4.CODICE) AS [Modello Princ.],
    RTrim(ARTICO1.CODICE) AS [Cod.Compatib.]
FROM
    ARTICO
LEFT JOIN 
    ARTSOS ON ARTSOS.IDARTICO = ARTICO.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    ARTICO ARTICO1 ON ARTSOS.IDARTSOS = ARTICO1.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    ARTCLA4 ON ARTCLA4.ID = ARTICO.IDARTCLA4
WHERE
    ARTICO.IDLINEEP = 4
```

`ARTICO.CODICE` can have duplicates because even if `articla4.codice` is always the same (related to `artico.codice`), `artico1.codice` can have multiple values.

I.E. Can be so

```
artico.codiceABC        articla4.codice001       artico1.codice001
artico.codiceABC        articla4.codice001       artico1.codice002
artico.codiceABC        articla4.codice001       artico1.codice003
```

and the result I'd like to get is this:

```
artico.codiceABC    articla4.codice001    artico.codice001,artico.codice002,artico.codice003
```

Comment: Your current select mentions _four_ columns, but the current output only appears to have three.  Can you explain this?

Comment: Yes, the second column is not relevant, it is the description of the article, it can be not considered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using SQL Server 2017 or later, we can try using the [standard approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server) to simulate group concatenation:

```
SELECT
    RTRIM(ARTICO.CODICE) AS [Cod.Ricambio],
    RTRIM(ARTICO.DESCR) AS Descrizione,
    RTRIM(ARTCLA4.CODICE) AS [Modello Princ.],
    [Cod.Compatib.] = STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + ARTICO1.CODICE
        FROM ARTICO ARTICO1
        WHERE ARTSOS.IDARTSOS = ARTICO1.ID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM ARTICO
LEFT JOIN ARTSOS
     ON ARTSOS.IDARTICO = ARTICO.ID
LEFT JOIN ARTCLA4
    ON ARTCLA4.ID = ARTICO.IDARTCLA4
WHERE
    ARTICO.IDLINEEP = 4;
```

Comment: I have tried but unfortunately it does not work :(  I have got the same result

Comment: Without seeing sample data, or better yet a demo, this is the best I can do.  I will leave this up for a while to maybe inspire someone else to get it right.

Comment: You are right, excuse me if i wasn't able to explain better my problem. I will do my best for send a better example. Anyway, the right field is idartsos that is related to artico1.id but i want to see artico1.codice. How can I show a demo or some sample datas?

Answer (score 0):

a friend of mine has told me one solution and it's ok but unfortunately it left a comma as last character. Ho can I remove this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    RTrim(ARTICO.CODICE) AS [Cod.Ricambio],
    RTrim(ARTICO.DESCR) AS Descrizione,
    RTrim(ARTCLA4.CODICE) AS [Modello Princ.],
    (
SELECT  RTrim(ARTICO1.CODICE) + ','  AS 'data()' 
FROM
    ARTICO A
LEFT JOIN 
    ARTSOS ON ARTSOS.IDARTICO = ARTICO.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    ARTICO ARTICO1 ON ARTSOS.IDARTSOS = ARTICO1.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    ARTCLA4 ON ARTCLA4.ID = ARTICO.IDARTCLA4
WHERE
    ARTICO.IDLINEEP = 4 AND A.CODICE = ARTICO.CODICE 
 FOR XML PATH('') 
) AS [Cod.Compatib.]
FROM
    ARTICO
LEFT JOIN 
    ARTSOS ON ARTSOS.IDARTICO = ARTICO.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    ARTICO ARTICO1 ON ARTSOS.IDARTSOS = ARTICO1.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    ARTCLA4 ON ARTCLA4.ID = ARTICO.IDARTCLA4
WHERE
    ARTICO.IDLINEEP = 4
```